# Are there any cases when For[] loops are reasonable?

Tags: programming, procedural-programming

To my mind the only reason for the existence of `For[]` loops in Mathematica is to allow new users with some experience in procedural programming languages to write simple Mathematica programs. The real problem is that sometimes such a user do not dive deeper and as a consequence he has 1) ugly and unreliable code and 2) a belief that "Mathematica has a C-like syntax".

It is hard for me to imagine a situation when `For[]` cannot be effectively and more cleanly replaced by `Table`, `Map`, anything else or `Do` at least. Am I wrong? Should we really recommend beginners to avoid `For[]` loops?

---

SUMMARY

There are actually two great answers. The first answer is the accepted one and the second answer is [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2164/219). I wish I could accept it as well.

Comment: No reason for them except simply because people want to use them. They're slow.

Mathematica has labels and Goto statements as well. I don't recommend them.

Comment: @Searke I've had one occasion where I used `Label` and `Goto`: figuring out what a FORTRAN code was doing.

Comment: Oops, I didn't know For was bad...!  The advantage, as I thought, over functional structures, was that you didn't accumulate temporary results like you do with Table. For example, in each iteration, I'd create a graphic, and write it to disk. If I used Table to collect images, Mathematica crashes after 10 minutes... I promise to read about Do tomorrow... :)

Comment: @cormullion Have a look at `Scan` as well. It is as close as one gets to loops from a functional side, but more rigid (iteration order is prescribed, and there are no iteration variables).

Comment: Perhaps if the algorithm you're implementing lends itself very well to loops your code will be most readable if you use loops.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To my mind, there are at least two cases when `For` loops are ok:

- Inside `Compile`, or in code which is being written with `Compile` in mind
- When your inner loops are vectorized or made efficient by some other means, so that each iteration of the `For` loop is sufficiently intensive computationally

Many efficient algorithms are procedural by nature and gain their efficiency by side effects and local mutations. When those algorithms contain nested loops, what matters the most is to speed up innermost loop(s). While we mostly tend to move away from `For` loops, I have no problem with a `For` loop being an outer loop in a program, as long as innermost loops are optimized. Also, `For` loops are more flexible than `Map` or `Scan` because you can use `Break` and `Continue`, and generally are not forced to iterate over all of the elements in a list in a prescribed order.

That said, I think we *should* recommend beginners to avoid `For` loops, just because this would allow them to change their mindset and get to the better understanding of Mathematica programming sooner. I'd say, it is ok to occasionally use `For` loops for experienced users, but beginners would be better off avoiding them entirely, until they get more experience with the language.

Comment: I am not sure I see where `For` loops are preferable to `Do`, which localizes the iterator (unless you are using `For` in a more complicated way than `For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Print[i]]`, but that is probably rare)

Comment: @acl I agree, that in many cases where `For` is used,  `Do` is what you really need. Some cases when you may want `For` (or `While`, which is its close relative), is when you either need more complex iteration, ot the number of iterations may not be known in advance (like e.g. in [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364804/a-fast-implementation-in-mathematica-for-position2d/8367453#8367453)), or when you want to use `Return` to return from the entire function containing a loop (using `Return` from `Do` will only break from `Do`).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I just noticed your comment here after posting an answer. Is `While` more efficient than `Do` or `Map` etc. if the range of iterations is unknown?

Comment: @Eli Lansey In uncompiled code, `Do` is typically more efficient that `While`, and `Map` can be much more efficient still, since it can *auto-compile* when the function being mapped is compilable. Note that `Map` is also different in that it procuduces the resulting list, while `Do` or `While` (or `For`) return `Null`. In compiled code, `Do` is still the fastest, and in my experience `While` comes second, and `Map` is somewhat slower IIRC.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Why don't WRIs make e.g. `For` auto-compiled ? I do not need any loops in Mma, but if they exist therein why aren't they better ?

Comment: @Artes This is hard to do in general, since generic Mathematica code can not be compiled. This is because of these reasons: 1.Mathematica is an untyped language? while for efficient compilation more type information would be needed 2. It is not clear how to compile rule-based code.  3. Mathematica is using an infinite evaluation model, which adds more complexity to the game (perhaps, there are other reasons as well). My own opinion is that Mathematica as a general-purpose language is often too general and would benefit from some intermediate (say, Python-style) language layer.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I see it if there are blocks of code combining loops and rule-based programming, moreover I understand  the general rule to beware of baroque style architecture in Mma.  Nonetheless even for rules there are some optimizing methods e.g. `Dispatch`.  So I think it is still a bit strange that `loops` aren't auto-compiled.

Comment: @Artes Compilation is not the same thing as optimization, I think. For compilation, you need some set (language) of lower-level primitives, so that you can express higher-level code as a sequence of those primitives. Since normally those primitives are more specialized ("closer to the hardware"), you get a speed-up because the program written entirely in that lower-level language can be interpreted more efficiently (or perhaps further compiled down to lower level still). Compiling generic Mathematica code is probably not possible or at the very least extremely hard, because compilation ...

Comment: @Artes ..flies in the face of extreme generality of the term-rewriting engine of Mathematica. A better strategy IMO would be to introduce more strongly typed sub-languages within Mathematica, so that programs written in those sub-languages could be compiled. This is the direction which I think has a great potential. In a sense, `Compile` defines one such sub-language, but I am sure it should be possible to define other sub-languages, and write custom compilers from those to C or whatever target language you want. Integrating those with efficient Mathematica low-level structures is hard though.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin in reply to [A better strategy IMO ...] I agree. Expression optimisation (without compilation to low level instructions) can also benefit from such restrictions IMO. But compilation to low level instructions is also very interesting. I find myself sticking only the functions that have analogues in SymbolicC whenever I write code that is intended to be compiled and most of the time translation to actual SymbolicC is quite straightforward and leads to great speedups. I hope that there will be more tools for such a workflow. By the way I also agree with your answer :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks. I'd actually like to do some work in this area of creating tools for such workflows.  It is hard to find time for that though, these days. Remains one of my pipe dreams )

Answer (score 36):

#### Choosing Adequate Loop-Constructs

While there are many loop-like constructs I think there are 5 that every Mathematica programmer should know, 4 of them come as pairs which either do return the result of each iteration or don't, but otherwise share syntax:

1. Map - Scan
2. Table - Do
3. While

As a general rule it is a good idea to always use the most simple construct that provides the functionality you need: A large majority of loop constructs do iterate over a given list/array and `Map` or `Scan` would be the best choice for these. They do away with any kind of indexing and iteration issues. In some cases it is useful/necessary to have a handle to a loop counter, this is what `Table` or `Do` provide. If you need a more flexible iteration scheme, then there is `While`, which is providing the most general case of a loop that I can think of. Using "more advanced" loop-like constructs in my opinion is only worth considering when they exactly match your use case and make that basically a one-liner. If you need tricks to map them to your use case that will often result in rather "write only" type of code. I would rather urge users to have a look at level specifications for `Map`/`Scan` and additional arguments for `Table`/`Do` (to specify nesting loops and step sizes) and the `Sow`/`Reap` mechanism to collect results from a arbitrary loop.

#### Why Not to Use `For`-Loops

While many of these other loop-like constructs in Mathematica have their use cases, I would strongly discourage the use of `For` loops: I have never used one in any Mathematica code I ever wrote. As mentioned by Leonid in one of the comments in most cases (I'd guess about 95% of the time when I see one) it is `Do` that is really needed. In the other maybe 5% it is `While` that is needed. The cases where one might think a `For` loop would be necessary can basically be reduced to two cases:

1. You need a loop counter: you'd better use `Do` or `Table`, their syntax is more concise, it is much easier to see what they actually do and they localize loop counters.
2. You need a more complex iteration scheme than what `Do` or `Table` provide: I prefer to use `While` for these cases since it is a lot easier to read and `For` doesn't add anything but unnecessary complexity.

I consequently use `Do`/`Table` for case 1 and `While` for case 2 (and only for case 2) so when I see `Do` or `While` in my code I readily get some extra information about the nature of the loop.

#### Readability of Code

A `While` loop is much easier to read than a `For` loop: There are basically three parts of code within such a loop: initialization, condition-check and body. In a `While` loop everything that happens before the `While` is initialization, the first argument of the `While` is the condition-check and the second is the body. In a `For` loop you can distribute the initialization between code before the `For` loop and the first argument, and you can arbitrarily distribute the body part between the 3rd and 4th argument. Consequently it will always need extra thinking about what will be evaluated in which order (see [Can this be written well, without loops?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2164/169) for an example: can you see the order of evaluation at first glance? I only realized that the loop counters were incremented after the nested loops after rewriting with `While`).

#### Technical Details and Performance

Concerning all the technical details I think `For` doesn't provide anything that `Do` and `While` don't: they return Null, they can be compiled (I would guess that both `Do` and `While` should even outperform `For` in compiled code), and you can use `Break` and `Continue` within them.

It is not only friendly to a possible reader to use the most simple construct that covers your need. It is just as well easier for Mathematica to understand your code, which lets it do a better job when optimizing the code (of course that holds just as well for other constructs than loops). Auto-compilation of Table is one case, here is another example:

```
res1 = Table[Table[i*j, {i, 100}], {j, 100}];
res2 = Table[i*j, {i, 100}, {j, 100}];
```

looks like not much difference and it's easy to check that these in fact create the same result, except for a small detail:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[res1]
Developer`PackedArrayQ[res2]

(* ==> False *)

(* ==> True *)
```

this can result in tremendous differences in the runtime and memory efficiency of this construct **and** all the following code which works with the result.

**EDIT**

There is one more important difference between a typical `For` loop and its `Do` correspondance which becomes clear when using floating point counters, compare e.g.:

```
h = 10.^-5;
Do[If[i >= 1 - h, Print[InputForm@i]], {i, 0, 1, h}]
```

to:

```
h = 10.^-5;
For[i = 0, i <= 1, i += h, If[i >= 1 - h, Print[InputForm@i]]]
```

Of course it really depends on what you want to achieve, but I think in most use cases you would actually prefer the equidistant division that `Do` seems to do over the accumulated errors of `For` which make it on my 64bit Mathematica 9 on Windows 7  "miss" the upper limit. It is again an example where Mathematica can act smarter when the construct you use is the simplest possible and thus more clear. If accumulating the errors would be what you actually *want* to happen, then again a `While` would still do the same thing with less ambiguities (again it took me a second try to realize that the increment in `For` is done **after** evaluating the body, something that is immediately clear in the `While` code and could accordingly be changed if so desired):

```
h = 10.^-5;
i = 0;
While[i <= 1, If[i >= 1 - h, Print[InputForm@i]]; i += h;]
```

Comment: +1. I actually consider `For` and `While` to be very close to each other, because both are inherited from C (in terms of syntax), where the difference between them is more a matter of personal preference (you can leave out some parts of `for` and have `while`, like `for(;condition;){}`). So when I was speaking of `For` loops, I meant both `For` and `While` (I should have stated that in my answer), and admittedly I also often prefer `While` to `For`.

Comment: @Leonid: you are of course right, and it might be worth mentioning that one can leave out parts in a Mathematica `For` as well (use `Null` if you don't want to see the syntax highlight warnings). But that is my criticism: `For` seems to add complexity without actually provide new features compared to `While`. Thus my preference for `While`: it doesn't add unnecessary load to my brain :-)

Comment: Yes, I agree. All your points are very valid. I think our answers are complementary to each other.

Comment: @AlbertRetey, hehe, here I could sneak in another +1 ;-)

Comment: A little remark: `readability of code` is rather subjective.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: of course code readability is to a large part subjective and strongly influenced by prior experience. But there are certainly several established rules which are widely accepted and which are beyond pure personal taste. Reduced complexity seems to be a very decent and **objective** measure of code readability to me which was why I mentioned it in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I'd argue that `For` should be used when you want to iterate through a list of options and insure that they are **not** run in parallel.

To give a silly example,  `Table[CelebrateBirthday[i],{i,0,18}]`  is equivalent to `For[i=0,i<19,i++,CelebrateBirthday[i]]`

However, a later programmer might try and performance tune by changing the first example into a `ParallelTable`, causing the birthdays to be celebrated in a non-deterministic order.  The `For` loop, on the other hand, signals to any future coders that the loop wasn't designed to be run in parallel and that care should be taken before changing the order of operations.

I'd tell a newbie that, if you *want* your code to run slowly, use `For`.  Otherwise, use `Table` or `Map`.

Comment: also, `Table` attempts to autocompile

Comment: Those would be equivalent if Table was Do

Comment: If you want a reader of your code to know that a loop is not to be parallelized I think a comment would server much better than the use of a suboptimal programming construct which, in principle, could be target of parallelization just as others...

Comment: @Albert  I agree that a comment would be the better options, but a belt and suspenders approach would argue that it makes sense to do both.  Also, while a programmer can sit down and try and turn a `For` loop into parallel code, already has a built in `ParallelTable`, `ParallelMap`, and `ParallelDo`, but no `ParallelFor`.  If a future programmer wants to parallelize the `For` loop, she's at least going to be forced to read the code first.

Answer (score 4):

I have used a `For` (or more usually `While`) loop in conjunction with `Sow` and `Reap` when I am unsure of the number of iterations I will be requiring. I'll iterate until a condition is met, and `Reap` all the solutions.

Note: There might be a better/faster way that I'm unaware of to do this same sort of thing.

Comment: I use `For` in the same circumstances, provided I don't know how many iterations I'm going to need and I also need an iteration counter. In some cases, it may be possible to work out the number of iterations outside the loop, in which case Table[] becomes useful, but if that determination is sufficiently complex and introduces the possibility of (programmer) error, Table[] may be an easier and potentially more robust solution.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody mentioned use of Throw, Catch for very versatile exiting from loops.

Comment: I actually would not recommend this technique for standard situations. If you have nested loops, you can wrap `Module` around them end exit with `Return[..., Module]`, or just `Return`. Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances IMO. Besides, people tend to abuse untagged exceptions, which are pretty bad (I consider `Throw` and `Catch` without tags a language defect), so this would just lead to lots of trouble IMO. Finally, exceptions cause an overhead, and I'd expect that they can not be compiled and will slow down the code if we use it (code) inside `Compile` (although I did not try it).

Comment: In my RootSearch package I call an iterative algorithm which looks for a root where there is likely to be a root. That algorithm calls a function which calls a function and so on. A few functions deep it may be discovered that the function whose roots we a looking fo is not defined at the new approximation of the root. When that happens I use Throw to give up on the iterative algorithm in that neighborhood. I don't know if you call that an exception. Also, we can use Check to take certain action when we compute 0/0 etc.

Comment: This sounds like a more involved flow of control than simply nested loops, in which case exceptions (`Throw`) may be justified. I expressed my views on this in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/634/error-checking-and-trapping-techniques-with-throw-and-catch/635#635), albeit in the context of error-checking. One thing I am absolutely opposed to is using `Throw` as `Throw[expr]` rather than `Throw[expr,tag]`. I think it is totally acceptable to use `Throw`-`Catch` to implement non-trivial flow of control, but this should be reserved for cases when nothing else helps.

Comment: Also, while it is hard for me to make conclusions without looking at the code, but normally, even for involved algorithms, I almost never saw a situation when the logic could not be implemented with local gotos (`Break`, `Continue`, etc) and *really* cried for `Throw`-`Catch`. I still think that these belong more to the software engineering side of the language than algorithmic, and should be used as such most of the time. This is just my opinion, of course, you don't have to agree with it.