# Can this be written well, without loops?

Tags: programming, functional-style

Inspired by [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2158/121) I would like to know if the following code can be written without explicit loops (For, While, etc.) in a clean, efficient and non-contrived way.  I have been unable to do so.

```
max = 5000;
a = ConstantArray[0, max];
x = y = z = n = 1;
val := 2 (2 n^2+(y-2) (z-2)+x (y+z-2)+2 n (x+y+z-3));
For[x = 1, val <= max, x++,
 For[y = 1, val <= max && y <= x, y++,
  For[z = 1, val <= max && z <= y, z++,
   For[n = 1, (r = val) <= max, n++,
    a[[r]]++
   ]; n = 1
  ]; z = 1
 ]; y = 1
]
```

The output is the array `a`.

Comment: Oh dear... ${}$

Comment: Can you give any more info as to where this code came from and how it is intended to be used?

Comment: @rcollyer I'm sorry, I cannot.  Functionally speaking it's all right there and fairly straightforward once you get past the ugliness.

Comment: @rcollyer Most likely a ProjectEuler problem. For some strange reason, `ListPlot[a]` looks very familiar...

Comment: Is `Do` allowed?

Comment: @faleichik only if it ends up "cleaner" than what is shown (obviously subjective; make a case for it). As I recall I did this several different ways but they were all uglier IMO than the `For` loops.  `Do` in the way I used it was essentially the same as the `For` loops but with less clarity.

Comment: The answer is yes. Everything can be written purely functional, and it's often much easier to read. However, it is often useful to know in advance what you want the program to do. Should I post this as an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: @David please don't be quite so smug.  The question is not if you have a Turing complete functional language but rather one of *style*.  If you have a *cleaner* solution, or even one that is much faster or something else you want to make the case for as superior, post *that* and I may accept it.

Comment: Well what are we supposed to do with this code snippet? There's no straightforward way of converting imperative to functional, it usually involves re-thinking your problem from a different viewpoint. This question however is primarily about decyphering your algorithm instead of doing the actual functional translation.

Comment: @David I cannot go into a lot of detail about the problem.  Consider `val` a black-box function and just look at the loop structure.  I think what that does it reasonably clear.

Comment: I have a very fast solution that only works for max=5000. It involves DumpSave and Get

Comment: @Rojo, your comment reminds me of a beautiful remark by O'Keefe in *The craft of Prolog*.  It's in a discussion of the problem:  find a 9-digit number, with distinct digits, such that the first n digits form a number divisible by n, for 1 ≤ n ≤ 9.  He goes through several optimisations, but concludes with (paraphrased) "you have to be careful, or eventually you will wind up optimising your program to `:- digits(381654729).`"(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydivisible_number#Background).

Comment: @JadeNB that was the spirit :)

Comment: Ohh, that's an interesting question - my gut feeling is there's something clean and magical for a solution.... +1

Comment: @ciao I had that feeling too.  I never did find that magic.  Perhaps you can.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are some features of this specific problem one can take advantage of.  The boundary of the `x,y,z,n` domain represented by `val <= max` is linear in `x,y,z` and only quadratic in `n`; furthermore `val` increases with each of the variables.  So basically the loops might be done in any order, and the limits might be solved for explicitly.

We'll start with the limit `max` and the expression `val`, which can be compiled for the sake of comparison.

```
max = 5000;
val[x_, y_, z_, n_] := 
  2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 2 n (x + y + z - 3));
valc = Compile[{{x, _Integer}, {y, _Integer}, {z, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}}, 
   2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 2 n (x + y + z - 3))];
```

We can then solve for the limits on the indices `z,y,x,n` and save them in `idxLimit[tag]`, where `tag` runs `1` through `4` and corresponds to `z,y,x,n` in that order.  (Here a function runs through the `tag`s and sets up `idxLimit`, but it could have been set up with separate formulas just as easily, as in the output below the code.)

```
Function[{tag}, idxLimit[tag] =
   Simplify[
     Min[{y, x, {}, {}}[[tag]], {z, y, x, n}[[tag]] /. 
       Last@Solve[(val[x, y, z, n] /. Take[{z -> 1, y -> 1, x -> 1}, tag - 1]) == max,
              {z, y, x, n}[[tag]] ]],
     n >= 1]
 ] /@ Range[4];
```

[image: info on idxLimit]

Next we make the table of the values

```
a = Normal@SparseArray[Rule @@@ #] &@
    Tally[Flatten[
      With[{i1 = {z, idxLimit[1]},
        i2 = {y, idxLimit[2]},
        i3 = {x, idxLimit[3]},
        i4 = {n, idxLimit[4]}},
       Table[valc @@ {x, y, z, n}, i4, i3, i2, i1] ] ]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.536007, Null} *)
```

Below is a table of timings (in sec.) that compares using `val` instead of `valc` and `ParallelTable` (on a 2-core machine).  It also compares the timing of the OP's `For`-loop program, with and without a compiled `val`.  The last line are the timings for `max = 20000`.

[image: Table of timings]

`Table` itself accounts for about `0.876687` sec. (`10.003417` for 20K).  Most of the rest of the time is for evaluation `valc` (about 7-8 sec. in the 20K case) or `val`.  A smaller chunk is spent collecting the results.  It seemed while I was playing with the problem, that `a[[r]]++` suffers from having to evaluate `a[[r]]` twice, once for reading and once for writing.  Perhaps it doesn't take that much time, but I felt like there was a limit to how fast I could accumulate results in `a` that way.  The `Table` way gains a little time at the expense of a lot more memory.

It's debatable whether solving for the limits (to get `idxLimit`) is clean.  The original `val` leads to the strange expressions.  Mainly it's a mathematical trick than a programming one, which allows a rather standard conversion of for loops to `Table`.  The rest of it are just tweaks.

Comment: I am going to Accept this.  Though it is not a purely programmatic solution and it didn't teach me a new coding trick as Simon's answer did it does finally provide a faster method than my `For` loops, and leverages *Mathematica*'s strengths to do so.

Answer (score 21):

I cannot write the code without any loops, but I have pared it down to a single `While` loop, making extensive use of short-circuiting to bail out of the expression at the appropriate point. Whether you consider this cleaner than nested `For` loops is a matter of taste. I personally find it easier to follow.

```
max=5000;
a={};
x=y=z=n=1;
val:=2 (2 n^2+(y-2) (z-2)+x (y+z-2)+2 n (x+y+z-3));

While@Or[
((r=val)<=max)&&(n++;a={a,r};True),
(n=1;++z<=y&&val<=max),
(z=1;++y<=x&&val<=max),
(y=1;x++;val<=max)
];

a=Tally@Flatten@a;
```

This gives `a` as a list of {position,value} pairs which you could use with something like `ListPlot`, or convert to the original form with `a = Normal@SparseArray[Rule@@@a]`

The code is a smidge faster than the original, but this is entirely due to building `a` as a linked list. The nested `For` loops are even faster if you make the same change.

---

For whatever reason the code above crashes *Mathematica 7* when `max` is higher.
Here is working v7 code using pre-allocation:

```
max = 5000;
a = ConstantArray[0, max];
x = y = z = n = 1;

val := 2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 2 n (x + y + z - 3));

While @ Or[
   (r = val) <= max && (n++; a[[r]]++; True),
   n = 1; ++z <= y && val <= max,
   z = 1; ++y <= x && val <= max,
   y = 1; x++; val <= max
 ];
```

Comment: That looks impressive!  I need time to digest this.

Comment: I must second that impression. That is some seriously interesting code.

Comment: I'm having trouble separating the linked list aspect of this from the underlying algorithm.  I quickly observe that the memory requirements of this are much greater than my original, and more troubling *Mathematica* crashes if `max` is greater than about 7500.  By the way `((r=val)<=max)&&(n++;a={a,r};True)` is a very interesting fragment of code; I don't think I've ever used `And` for conditional evaluation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the increased memory usage is because of the linked list approach. In your code `a` is a Packed Array, in mine it isn't - I simply accumulate values of `r` and tally them afterwards. You can replace `a={a,r}` in my `While` loop by `a[[r]]++` to make it build `a` the same way your code does. I'm not getting any crashes. With `max=10000` I get a `ByteCount` for `a` of about 80MB (compared to 40kB for your code) and `MemoryInUse` is about 100MB.

Comment: @Simon, okay, I'll try `a[[r]]++` later tonight and report.  Regarding infix, that's just a precedence problem:  `(1 < 2) ~Or~ Print["!"];`

Comment: Interestingly this code *appears* to compile but it doesn't work (instant evaluation and `a` unchanged).  I think your use of `And` and `Or` is quite atypical.  Don't misunderstand, I like that.

Comment: Re the precedence problem - thanks. Seems obvious now! I'm going to delete that comment as it's misleading.

Comment: Re the compiling problem, it seems like there might be a difference between v7 and v8. This works on v8: `f=Module[{x,y,z,n,a,r},With[{val=2(2n^2+(y-2)(z-2)+x(y+z-2)+2n(x+y+z-3))},Compile[{{max,_Integer}},Block[{a=Table[0,{max}],x=1,y=1,z=1,n=1,r=0},While@Or[(r=val)<=max&&(n++;a[[r]]++;True),n=1;++z<=y&&val<=max,z=1;++y<=x&&val<=max,y=1;x++;val<=max];a]]]]; a=f[5000];`

Answer (score 17):

**EDIT To address hard-coded `Table` and `SparseArray` limits, and efficiency**

As pointed out in the comments, hard-coded limits on the `Table` or `SparseArray` dimensions may not work in general. Besides being slow, the `Table` approach quickly eats up system memory for moderate values of `max`. Here is a variation on WReach's recursive scheme using `ReplaceRepeated`. With `max=5000`, it is about a factor of 4 slower than using `For`.

```
Clear[max, a4];
max = 5000;
a4 = ConstantArray[0, max];
ReplaceRepeated[{1, 1, 1, 1},
 {
  {x_, y_, z_, n_} /; (r = 2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 2 n (x + y + z - 3))) 
                      <= max :> (If[z <= y <= x, a4[[r]]++]; {x, y, z, n + 1}),
  (* Stop *)
  {x_, 1, 1, 1} :> Null,
  (* Optimizations *)
  {x_, y_, 1, 1} :> If[y < x, {x, y + 1, 1, 1}, {x + 1, 1, 1, 1}],
  {x_, y_, z_, 1} :> If[z < y, {x, y, z + 1, 1}, {x, y + 1, 1, 1}],
  {x_, y_, z_, _} :> If[z < y, {x, y, z + 1, 1}, 
                        If[y < x, {x, y + 1, 1, 1}, {x + 1, 1, 1, 1}]]
 }
 , MaxIterations -> Infinity]
```

**(Array-based solutions)**

As far as readability, `Table` comes to mind:

```
Clear[val, a1, max];
max = 100;
a1 = ConstantArray[0, max];
val := 2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 2 n (x + y + z - 3));
Table[If[val <= max, a1[[val]]++], {x, 1, max}, {y, 1, x}, {z, 1, y}, {n, 1, max}];

a1==a
 (* True (at least for max=100) *)
```

I think this fulfils your "clean" and "non-contrived" criteria, but it is definitely not efficient: I set max to 100 because I didn't feel like waiting more than a few minutes for the answer!

**EDIT**

Also using `Table`, but without the `If`:

```
Clear[max, vals, a2];
max = 100;
vals = Table[2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 
  2 n (x + y + z - 3)), {x, 1, max}, {y, 1, x}, {z, 1, y}, {n, 1, 
max}];
a2 = BinCounts[Flatten@vals, {1, max + 1, 1}]
```

**EDIT for `SparseArray`**

Here is an approach using `SparseArray` in place of `Table` to get vals in the above. It is somewhat more efficient than `Table`, but not as efficient as the `For` loop way:

```
Clear[max, val, vals, a3];
max = 100;
vals = SparseArray[{x_, y_, z_, n_} /; 2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 
      2 n (x + y + z - 3)) <= max && z <= y <= x :> 2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 2 n (x + y + z - 3)), {max, max, max, max}];
a3 = Normal@BinCounts[Flatten@vals, {1, max + 1, 1}]

a3==a
 (* True *)
```

There is probably a way to make the condition more readable, but I haven't found it.

Consider the relative timings for `max==100`:

- `For` loops
   ~ 0.006 s
- `Table`
   ~ 162 s
- `SparseArray`
   ~ 0.8 s

But even `SparseArray` becomes horribly slow for `n = 200`.

Comment: Yes, the problem here is that we do not exit the loop when `val > max` -- one can hack it with `Return` or the like but it makes it *more* ugly instead of less.

Comment: The problem (apart from efficiency issues you noted) is that, in general, you can not know that `x`, `y`, `z` and `n` should only change within the interval `{1,max}`. You can probably *prove* it in some cases, but that's probably besides the point.

Comment: You can always use `Break` in your table to escape early. I wouldn't necessarily call that clean, though! :)

Comment: @Pillsy right, but then you are better off using `For`.

Comment: @Leonid I do hope you have a solution for me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry to disappoint. I gave it a try, but, at least within the time I could spend on it today, did not get anything exciting. I toyed with `Table` (very similarly to the above answer), but wasn't satisfied with it for the reasons I outlined in my comment. Might revisit it later when I get some more time, but this does not look promising to me. I think, there are problems for which procedural formulation is natural, and those for which functional is, and we have to live with that. Wasn't this the point you wanted to make when asking  your question?

Comment: That's better written as a `Do` loop since the point is the side effect, not the collected result.  That'd be more memory efficient.

Comment: @Leonid at heart I am still hoping for an amazing, fast, clean, terse solution, but if it is not found, then yes, I would post this to the first question referenced as an example of when `For` loops work well.

Comment: You could write that table line in a horrible way with the Break like this, `If[val <= max, a1[[val]]++, Break[, Table]]~Table~{z, 1, y}~
  Table~{y, 1, x}~Table~{x, 1, max}~Table~{n, 1, max};`

Comment: @JxB +1 for the `SparseArray` solution, although I stand by my remark that in general we don't know what the intervals for the variables `x`, ... should be.

Comment: Isn't `Table` just syntactic sugar for a loop anyway?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a version where the iterations are expressed recursively instead of imperatively:

```
Module[{val, iter, max, a}
, max = 5000
; a = ConstantArray[0, max]
; val[x_, y_, z_, n_] :=
    2 (2 n^2+(y-2) (z-2)+x (y+z-2)+2 n (x+y+z-3))
; iter[x_] /; val[x, 1, 1, 1] <= max :=
    (iter[x, 1]; iter[x + 1])
; iter[x_, y_] /; y <= x && val[x, y, 1, 1] <= max :=
    (iter[x, y, 1]; iter[x, y + 1])
; iter[x_, y_, z_] /; z <= y && val[x, y, z, 1] <= max :=
    (iter[x, y, z, 1]; iter[x, y, z + 1])
; iter[x_, y_, z_, n_] :=
    val[x, y, z, n] /. v_ /; v <= max :> (++a[[v]]; iter[x, y, z, n+1])
; Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, iter[1]]
; ListPlot[a]
] // Timing
```

On my machine, it runs about twice as slow as the `For` version.

Comment: This is nice: it makes the tree structure of the problem manifest. +1

Answer (score 9):

This is an interesting, if (necessarily) ill-posed question. My approach is to couch it in more general terms and attempt to clarify what is possible, natural and generalizable by exploring the meaning of  "clean", "efficient" and "non-contrived". Some implications for language design are also discussed.

```
max = 5000;
val := 2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 2 n (x + y + z - 3));
ai[i_] := Length@Solve[val == i && x >= y >= z >= 1 && n >= 1, {x, y, z, n}, Integers];

a = Table[ai[i], {i, 1, max}]


(*
   - Warning: On a personal machine this is likely to take several hours;
   for plausibility setting max = 100 takes less than 1 min to complete.

   - Acknowledgment: This was computed at the Pawsey Supercomputing Center
    ( ~18 min on 12 kernels with ParallelTable replacing Table).

*)
```

Hence as per the OP's request, the code is written without loops and is also, I'd argue, clean, non-contrived, (space) efficient; offers lazy evaluation for `a`'s components and provides additional context. It is however, manifestly and grossly inferior from a time-efficiency viewpoint needing HPC resources to even confirm its equivalence with previous implementations. Its conceptualization however, dilineates likely limitations.

**Background:**

One point alluded to, but not emphasised in the answers/comments is that constructs like `Table`, `Array`, `SparseArray` etc. all "explicitly define" a space, whereas `For`, `While` etc. loops describe processes via *stopping conditions*. The former commonly:

- Specify a space of elements
- Specify how that space is traversed
- Specify computations on visited elements during the traversal

directly and more naturally (arguably because humans are more visual than logical creatures). Looping constructs like `For`, on the other hand, can be co-opted into defining spaces with the above features but often do so sub-optimally as their stopping conditions end up getting in the way.

The underlying space being defined in the question is not immediately obvious, as evidenced by initially resorting to loops but the deeper question seemingly being proposed is how permanent is this state of affairs? is there a systematic way of re-casting into more functional-like `Table`/`Array` forms? Unfortunately the answer turns out to be no, although there is usually more that can be done; first though, consider how this particular loop *could* be translated into a `Table` form albeit in a way apparently insufficiently "magical" or "programmatical"  - by analyzing `val`'s particular structure and mathematical properties.

First, it can be noted that the `For` loop terminates since `val`'s quadratic increase in `n` is guaranteed to eventually exceed `max`. The actual iterates over which this takes place however, is not immediately obvious corresponding to the non-obviousness of converting into a `Table`/`Array` formulation. MichaelS2's answer, alone amongst all the responses, explicitly finds iterates thereby arriving at a non-loop solution as originally requested (it is on this basis, I'd argue, that his answer merited acceptance rather than from the stated efficiency gains (other `Table`/`SparseArray` solutions assumed, stopping properties related to `val` [as acknowledged in the comments] while all the other answers have loops lurking somewhere within `While`'s or recursive procedures).

[Note that even this loop dichotomy can't be pushed too far; a stopping condition can be inserted into a `Table`'s iterates thereby turning it into a "Loop" whilst explicit iterates in a `For` loop can augment stopping-conditions thereby turning it into a "`Table`"]

Converting to a `Table` formulation by finding explicit iterates however, required analyzing `val` in the stopping condition with the specific nature of such analysis unavoidable thereby dashing the OP's hopes and intuition (admittedly also my own) for a generic, "magical", "programming solution" for loop conversion. This follows since to assume otherwise would mean being able to translate arbitrary `For` stopping conditions into decidable procedures (those characteristic of `Table`-like iterates), something impossible from the Halting Problem's unsolvability. For some examples therefore, the traversal simply has to be stepped through (imagine a random `val` to simulate a black box function).

The `Solve` reformulation conceptualizes `a` as a vector who's *i'th* component counts the number of "essentially different" solutions to the Diophantine equation: `val == i`. Here "essentially different", means up to re-labeling the `x`, `y`,`z` variables and is implemented by translating `For`'s stopping conditions that effectively insist on the variable ordering `x>=y>=z>=1`.

The explict values of `Table` iterates correspond to upper bounds on the size of integers in any putative solution. Diophantine equations are often used to settle decidability questions which here emerges in the form of systematising code re-writing attempts.

In terms of (time) efficiency implications, one pertinent issue is whether or not these counts can be performed *without* explicitly generating actual solutions. `SatisfiabilityCount` offers an interface for doing so in relation to `Boolean` equations although its performance suggests solutions are first generated before being counted.

A [Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheSatisfiabilityThreshold/) shows that while it is possible to generate closed-form formulae for counting solutions *without* their explicit generation for classes of equations (albeit over small dimensions).

In general however, counting problems of #P complexity are generally intractable and the point of couching the problem in number-theoretic terms is that it can show you what you are up against in terms of searching for efficiency gains. I suspect that existing complexity results for counting solutions of diophantine equations makes the prospects of significant improvements in this example very limited.

Intuitively, `a` depends on visiting every element in the `For` loop with any significant efficiency gains stemming from being able to short-cut this process. The exhibited efficiency gain (with the `Table` solution) does this in a limited (if clever and useful) way by using `max` (effectively bypassing the stopping condition as the means for ignoring those variable values for which `val` exceeds `max`) while also exploiting *Mathematica*'s implementation of `Table` (its compilability and parallelization).

The core "irreducibility" of this computation however, can be first discerned by observing `a`'s "randomness" for the first 5K elements:

[image]

with some order emerging from seeing the first 50K elements:

[image]

but all the while random-like upper boundary persisting as evident from viewing the first 250K elements:

[image]

```
(* Acknowledgement:
   - The above plots used the compiled "Table" from Michael's answer.
   - The last 250K plot used the resources of the Pawsey Supercomputing Centre
     in Perth, Western Australia (taking ~15 min with 12 Kernels and ParallelTable) 
 *)
```

indicating the absence of a recursive reducibility (e.g. impossibility of expressing `a[[i]]` in terms of `a[[j]]`'s for `j<i` ). Consider however, a similar example instead involving the expression `val2` (derived from `val` by replacing `n^2` with `n` and removing the later occurrence of `2n`). Now there is evidence of clear reducibility.

[image]

The reducibility inherent in the the "`val2` computation" suggests opportunities for efficiency gains in codified mathematical knowledge, say that built-in to functions like `Solve`; sure enough it outperforms the `For` loop for finding `a[[5000]]` (17.73 s vs 120.27 s) in contrast to its inferior performance in relation to the more "irreducible `val` computation" (5.82 s vs 2.07 s).

[image]

To be sure, finding a single element of `a` is `Solve`'s focus in contrast to `For`'s focus here in generating *all* of `a`'s elements. On the other hand, this also indicates one might have anticipated `Solve`'s more competitive performance (notwithstanding its impressive generality and suggesting its improvement by associating predicates corresponding to `For`'s stopping conditions together with preliminary checks on identifying/looking-up irreducibility);  at any rate, the same effects would be observable given a mature counting framework in *Mathematica* (i.e. functions for which counting *was* the focus).

There are also many implications for language design here but this post is plenty wordy already.

Well some implications:

The conventional wisdom seems to be that `For`'s should be afforded sideways glances before being cast off into outer darkness while moving into the utopia of `Table`-`Array` vectorization. While this view carries a certain force (I can't imagine programming without `Tables`/`Arrays`) IMO such unyielding focus on functional programming can also become limiting.

Firstly, while `Tables`/`Arrays` represent powerful ways of exploring the computational universe, they do so in a regimented way progressively fixing variable dimensions that while easily humanly graspable potentially ignore potentially fruitful search spaces. In addition, they also tend to push answers in directions that may [not even require](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27468/2249) brute-force enumeration. Even in situations where brute-force enumeration is apparently unavoidable however, (such as the irreducibility illustrated here) certain types of questions necessitate a different, "more semantic" approach. This is possibly foreshadowed in [pure math initiatives](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2014/08/computational-knowledge-and-the-future-of-pure-mathematics/) but more broadly it also has implications in the scientific practice of model-building.

The process of identifying this problem (from apparently Project Euler) involved a type of reverse-engineering, analogs of which frequently occur in general modeling. To relate it back to the problem at hand: It's not necessarily the case that saying (or computing) something useful about `a[[i]]` should require computing its exact value. As a toy example, in a more "semantic" computing environment, `ZeroQ[a[[(googol=10^100)-1]]` should return `True` *without* setting out to generate the structure `a` or the exact value of `a[[googol-1]]`  (n.b. current output of `PossibleZeroQ[googol]` or `PossibleZeroQ[googol^googol]`)

This suggests notions of "`LazyTable`", "`LazyArray`" analogs (`SemanticArray`, `DelayedArray` or `Array` overloaded?) that move gracefully between producing actual structures when immediately, computationally feasible and otherwise; accessing pre-computed databases and/or remaining unevaluated in readiness for input into computational questions about `a[[i]]` (i.e. that don't require its exact value).

While the `ZeroQ` question/computation here is toy, situations inevitably arise in which the computation forms a link in a useful (computational/reasoning) chain and/or it is in fact the *only* way to identify the origin of the original computation. Consider a (hidden) `For` loop representing an irreducible natural process in which say `a[[googol;;googol+100]]`, constitutes the output of 100 experimental observations (i.e. `a`'s index corresponds to time). Due to irreducibility it may be impossible to run the computation again to deduce such provenance but nonetheless, computations about `a[googol;;googol+100]` (i.e. beyond `ZeroQ`) potentially exhibit identifying fingerprints traceable back to the originating `For` process. This however, requires `For`'s original framing and collation (or equivalents) in "lazy" terms.

This computational gap is a fundamental limitations of the (still) amazingly useful look-up tables such as the [On-line Encyclopadia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org), (n.b. `FindSequenceFunction`) but functions like "`LazyTable`" at least provide a mechanism for overcoming such gaps by generalizing this collation. It portends the usefulness of (inter-related) look-up tables for lists of functions and/or symbols backed by their networked connections (integers as algorithmic fingerprints owe as much to a human's proclivity for counting things as anything else); in so doing significant parts of scientific inquiry can be automated given how modeling/simulations often embody precisely this reverse-engineering process.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  It's going to take some time to fully appreciate but I already find it of value.  And you note that I *did* Accept Michael's answer and not simply on the grounds of speed but on the analytical approach taken.

Comment: I find your closing line tantalizing: "There are also many implications for language design here but this post is plenty wordy already."

Comment: Yes, and of course irrespective, it is the OP's perogative :)

Comment: By the way, and no offense intended, this kind of direct `Solve` formulation was what I was trying to avoid with the requirement of efficiency.  I would very much have liked it to be fast but it was not and I eventually aborted it.  At the time I posted this I was very much against posting Project Euler problems, hence the obfuscation, but I've since come to realize it is a losing battle, so I suppose the question might be clarified.

Comment: None taken and yes I did suspect such reverse-engineering might be a possibility and I would agree that it can't hurt to be up-front. Doesn't this however, say something about Solve's implementation - shouldn't its efficiency be comparable to a (For) "brute force" enumeration?

Comment: What a wonderful essay this has become.  While I originally hoped for a concise and fast alternative to the For structure I think your reasoning about functional programming and the design of language is even more valuable.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes fruitful questions occupy that happy place between precision and vagueness.Yes didn't quite answer your question but a fairly high bar was set - it seems that to answer comprehensively, not only did the Halting problem need solving but also demonstrating that $NP=P$ (all the while strategically channeling Euler!) - mind you, to be fair, for conjuring such magic, SE bounties were dangled.

Answer (score 8):

I have a solution that I think is somewhat cleaner, and which still completes in a reasonable (but considerably longer) amount of time, and based on my desultory testing, it seems to scale with `max` at the same rate that the original version does. However, where on my machine the original version takes about 3 sec. to complete for `max = 5000`, my version takes about 40 sec. to complete.

Here's my solution.

```
valuesToCounts[vals_, max_] := Normal@SparseArray[Rule @@@ Tally[vals], {max}]

countN[fun_, max_, range_, x_, y_, z_] :=
 With[{closure = fun[x, y, z, #] &},
  valuesToCounts[closure /@ TakeWhile[range, closure@# <= max &], 
   max]]

countZ[fun_, max_, range_, x_, y_] :=
 Total[countN[fun, max, range, x, y, #] & /@ 
   TakeWhile[range, fun[x, y, #, 1] <= max && # <= y &]]

countY[fun_, max_, range_, x_] :=
 Total[countZ[fun, max, range, x, #] & /@ 
   TakeWhile[range, fun[x, #, 1, 1] <= max && # <= x &]]

countX[fun_, max_, range_] :=
 Total[countY[fun, max, range, #] & /@ 
  TakeWhile[range, fun[#, 1, 1, 1] <= max &]]
```

At the risk of belaboring the point, and compromising the functional purity of my solution, I tried to improve performance by using a closure to emulate pass-by-reference (a Mathematica trick I heartily recommend), like so:

```
scanN[fun_, scanner_, max_, range_, x_, y_, z_] :=
 With[{closure = fun[x, y, z, #] &},
  Scan[scanner, closure /@ TakeWhile[range, closure@# <= max &], max]];

scanZ[fun_, scanner_, max_, range_, x_, y_] :=
 scanN[fun, scanner, max, range, x, y, #] & /@ 
  TakeWhile[range, fun[x, y, #, 1] <= max && # <= y &];

scanY[fun_, scanner_, max_, range_, x_] :=
 scanZ[fun, scanner, max, range, x, #] & /@ 
  TakeWhile[range, fun[x, #, 1, 1] <= max && # <= x &];

scanX[fun_, scanner_, max_, range_] :=
 scanY[fun, scanner, max, range, #] & /@ 
  TakeWhile[range, fun[#, 1, 1, 1] <= max &];

countByScanning[fun_, max_] :=
  Module[{a = ConstantArray[0, max], range = Range[max]},
   scanX[fun, (a[[#]]++) &, max, range];
   a];
```

There's a fair amount of code repetition here; I suspect with a little more work it could be massaged into something even prettier. Still, it's a good deal slower, so it might not be worth the candle.

Answer (score 7):

My solution is not elegant but at least it is rather fast. The idea is similar to the other answers. I create one big and clumsy iterator instead of four simple ones. In order to compare timings I need to say that `AbsoluteTiming` of the original code on my machine for `max=5000` is `4.7806686`.

```
ClearAll[next, step, val];
max = 5000;

pat = {x_, y_, z_, n_};
val[pat] := 
  2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 2 n (x + y + z - 3));
a1 = ConstantArray[0, max];

next[pat] := Which[
   x != y == z == n == 1, 0,
   (x >= y && z == n == 1) || x == y == z, {x + 1, 1, 1, 1},
   (x > y > z && n == 1) || x > y == z, {x, y + 1, 1, 1},
   x >= y > z, {x, y, z + 1, 1}
   ];

step[p : pat] := If[
   (r = val@p) <= max, a1[[r]]++; {x, y, z, n + 1},
   next@p
   ];

NestWhile[step, {1, 1, 1, 1}, ! (# === 0) &]; // AbsoluteTiming
a1 == a

(*==>   {7.2491184, Null} 
        True *)
```

The slow-down ratio is `1.5`.
The difference in speed here is because of ugly exit condition and redundant comparisons. As long as we want only to avoid `For` we can do something like this:

```
ClearAll[next, val];
ClearSystemCache[];
max = 5000;
x = y = z = n = 1;
val := 2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 
     2 n (x + y + z - 3));
a1 = ConstantArray[0, max];

run = True;

next := Which[
   x != y == z == n == 1, run = False,
   x == y == z || (x >= y && z == n == 1), (x++; y = z = n = 1),
   x > y == z || (x > y > z && n == 1), (y++; z = n = 1),
   x >= y > z, (z++; n = 1)
   ];

While[run,
  If[(r = val) <= max, a1[[r]]++; n++, next]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
a1 == a

(* {5.1868692, Null}
   True *)
```

Nevertheless I did not manage to beat the original code in speed (I don't speak about the elegance for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 5):

a 'loopless' one liner.. This takes ~5 minutes, way slower than the original, but considerably faster that Ronald's..

```
 max = 5000;
 Clear[val, x, y, z, n]
 val[x_, y_, z_, n_] := 
      2 (2 n^2 + (y - 2) (z - 2) + x (y + z - 2) + 2 n (x + y + z - 3));
 a = Normal@
    SparseArray[Rule @@@ #, max] &@(val[x, y, z, n] /. 
          FindInstance[  val[x, y, z, n] <= max &&  
              x >= y >= z >= 1 && n >= 1, {x, y, z, n} , Integers, 10^6] //
               Tally);
```

Unfortunately we need to supply `FindInstance` with a bound on the number of instances..

Comment: Indeed, but the bound means the computation is "not certain" - some certainty has been sacrificed for speed. Admittedly though, it doesn't seem like much certainty has been sacrificed looking at the graphs. The 1M bound seems overly conservative although curiously, dropping it seems to add a few minutes to the computation.