# Creating a table/Matrix during a For loop

Tags: matrix

I have a `For` loop (with `i` as a counter), which calculates different values (`y1`, `y2`, `y3`,...) as a function of the variable `x`.
How can I create a table/matrix which contains `i` lines, each line containing the variable `x_i` and the values (`y1_i`, `y2_i`, `y3_i`,...)?

Comment: Hi @Solarboy, welcome to MMA.SE. In the future, it would be helpful to have a minimal example of what you've tried. That way the answers can be more specific.

Comment: A relevant doc page [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstructingLists.html).

Answer (score 16):

Typically the best way to accumulate results from an arbitrary process is to use [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html).

I picked four functions of `i` as an example.  Since there are four, I [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) at the end into subsets of four:

```
Reap[
  For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, Sow[i]; Sow[i^2]; Sow[i!]; Sow[N@Log@i]];
][[2, 1]] ~Partition~ 4
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 0.},
>  {2, 4, 2, 0.693147},
>  {3, 9, 6, 1.09861},
>  {4, 16, 24, 1.38629},
>  {5, 25, 120, 1.60944},
>  {6, 36, 720, 1.79176},
>  {7, 49, 5040, 1.94591},
>  {8, 64, 40320, 2.07944},
>  {9, 81, 362880, 2.19722}}
> ```

If you can formulate your code to do a single `Sow` for each row it will be cleaner:

```
Reap[
  For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, Sow[{i, i^2, i!, N@Log@i}]];
][[2, 1]]
```

---

Brett Champion recommended that I show the two argument from of `Sow`, which groups results according to explicit tags.

> Sow[*e*, *tag*]
>   specifies that *e* should be collected by the nearest enclosing Reap whose pattern matches *tag*.
>
> Sow[*e*, {*tag*<sub>1</sub>, *tag*<sub>2</sub>, ...}]
>   specifies that e should be collected once for each pattern that matches a *tag*<sub>i</sub>.

(See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2423/121) for a powerful use of the multiple tag form.)

Here is an example using this in place of `Partition` in the case of separate `Sow` expressions per loop.

```
Reap[
 For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, Sow[i, i]; Sow[i^2, i]; Sow[i!, i]; Sow[N@Log@i, i]];
][[2]]
```

---

Also, with a [few](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2158/121) [exceptions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2164/121) it is better to avoid `For` in *Mathematica* and use constructs such as `Table`, `Do`, `Array`, `Map`, `NestWhile`, `FixedPointList` and others.  I chose to answer your direct question rather than to answer with what I think you should use instead.  If you are interested in alternative ways to write your program you should post a new question to that effect with an example `For` loop you wish to optimize.

Comment: Glad someone brought up `Sow` and `Reap`...  You should mention the two-argument form, though, since otherwise you can run into problems down the road. (Like needing to resort to `Partition`.)

Comment: Why didn't you use `Do` instead of `For`? For these cases (doing simple tests) it shows as a faster solution.

Comment: @FJRA you already showed a "better" way using `Table`.  István references `Array`.  I wanted to answer the OP's question directly and show best how results may be accumulated from within `For` or any other construct.

Comment: @Brett I'll add an example.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard your last comment points out what István started saying: there are a million ways to do this!

Comment: As an added point, in why to avoid `For` and `Do`, is they do not produce any output.

Comment: What does the [[2,1]] at the end of the Reap command mean? If it's in the documentation, where can I find it? (I don't see an explanation in the documentation for the "Reap" command)

Comment: @Allure It is a shorthand for [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).  `Reap` returns more information than I need, so I extract only what I want.

Answer (score 12):

Try using `Table`, assuming `x` is an array of values you could try:

```
matrix = Table[{xi, y1[xi], y2[xi], ..}, {xi, x}]
```

`Table` will "do the `For` loop" while building `matrix`, in this case `xi` will take each value of `x`.

And if `y` functions is also an array, you can use a nested `Table`:

```
matrix = Table[{xi, Sequence@@Table[y[xi,j], {j, n}]}, {xi, x}]
```

Here `j` is the index for the second table, which will run from `1` to `n`.

Answer (score 6):

Now this is the kind of question that can be answered in a million ways:

```
yRange = 4;
iRange = 6;

(* using Table & Map *)
Table[{Subscript[x, i], 
   Sequence @@ Map[Subscript[y, #, i] &, Range[yRange]]}, {i, 
   6}] // Column

(* using Map & Table *)
Map[Prepend[Table[Subscript[y, j, #], {j, yRange}], 
    Subscript[x, #]] &, Range[iRange]] // Column

(* using MapThread & Array *)
MapThread[
  Prepend,
  {Transpose@Array[Subscript[y, ##] &, {yRange, iRange}], 
   Array[Subscript[x, ##] &, {iRange}]}] // Column
```

All returning:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Without having your for loop in hand, you could also do something like the following:

```
myMatrix = {}; (* Initialize the list *)

For[i=0, i<Something, i++, 
  (* ... you do something here *)
  AppendTo[myMatrix,{xi, y1[xi], y2[xi], ..}]

  (* ... do other things .. *)
]
```

Or you could combine the a call to `Table` as @FJRA suggests for the "inner loop" `j` with the `For` loop like above.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks for the edit, I guess I was writing too many comments :)