# Creating Lists From Loops

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following:

```
lists = Import["G:/Notebooks/Lists.csv"];

col7 = lists [[All, 7]];

For[i=0,i<101,i++,Print[Count[col7,i]]]
```

This will get a 100 cells printed out but what I really want to do is capture this output to another variable *as a list*. So far the best way I have figured out is to copy the output, edit the text, and manually paste it back in to a variable. There surely has to be a better way?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/creating-a-table-matrix-during-a-for-loop , asked just an hour or so ago?

Comment: It has some similarity. In one example, AppendTo was used. I have tried AppendTo, and it doesn't work. I am also not dealing with a table, just want a one dimensional list of data. I have tried about 5 different ways I could think of to accomplish this using the list manipulation commands and I cannot seem to coax mma to do this.

Comment: I really don't understand why `Table` doesn't work for you, but maybe I'm just too tired.  Can you explain?

Comment: @Sinistar: how does the AppendTo not work? Did you define the variable (such as `col7 = {}`) before using it in AppendTo? Note that `AppendTo[col7,someList]` is the same as `col7 = Append[col7,someList]` but both require `col7` in this case to be defined

Comment: @tkott It didn't work because you used the wrong brackets. I've edited your answer in the other post.

Comment: A relevant doc page [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstructingLists.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the solution to this kind of problems is using `Table`:

```
Table[Count[col7, i], {i, 100}]
```

However, in this case I suggest `Tally` or `BinCounts`:

```
Tally[col7]

BinCounts[col7, {0, 100, 1}]
```

Tally will not list elements that don't appear at all.

Comment: Seems to be effective...

Answer (score 4):

In addition `Array` and `Map` work. *Thanks Mr.Wizard*. There are some subtle differences in their arguments the documentation does a good job of explaining them.

I assume you were looking for counts of the occurrences of values 0 - 100 in col7.

```
min = 0;
max = 9; (* In your example it would be 100 *)
col7 = RandomInteger[{min, max}, max*10];

a = {}; For[i = min, i <= max, i++, AppendTo[a, Count[col7, i]]]; a

Array[Count[col7, #] &, max + 1 - min, min]

Map[Count[col7, #] &, Range[min, max]]

Table[Count[col7, i], {i, min, max}]

Sort[Tally[col7], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &][[All, 2]]

BinCounts[col7, {min, max + 1, 1}]
```

*Results:*

```
{6, 11, 14, 6, 11, 9, 7, 10, 7, 9}
{6, 11, 14, 6, 11, 9, 7, 10, 7, 9}
{6, 11, 14, 6, 11, 9, 7, 10, 7, 9}
{6, 11, 14, 6, 11, 9, 7, 10, 7, 9}
{6, 11, 14, 6, 11, 9, 7, 10, 7, 9}
{6, 11, 14, 6, 11, 9, 7, 10, 7, 9}
```

The numbers will vary because of how I generated col7, but they should be the same for all six  examples.

*Performance results:*

```
min = 0;
max = 100;
col7 = RandomInteger[{min, max}, 10000];
```

[image]

Comment: Nice comparison.  The custom sort `#1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &` is not needed (and slower) because the default sort function will produce the same result in this case.  Also, it is faster to use `SortBy` to sort by the first element, if you need to do that explicitly:  `SortBy[. . ., First]`