# How to Map FindMinimum instead of using a For loop to return distance output?

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization, procedural-programming

I am looking for the distance between the spatial median of a subset of points to all original points in the set preferences to model group decision making. I can build a for loop to return the subsets spatial medians but am having trouble extracting the optimized distances. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
n = 5
preferences = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 2], {n, 2}]
dtotal[f_] := Total[Sqrt[Total[(Transpose[f] - {x, y})^2]]]
sodtotal = FindMinimum[dtotal[preferences], {x}, {y}]
sopt = {x /. sodtotal[[2]], y /. sodtotal[[2]]}
sodist = sodtotal[[1]]
SpatialMedian[preferences]
prefsub = Subsets[preferences, {1, n}]
subdtotal = Map[dtotal, Subsets[preferences, {1, n}]]
subopt = {}
For[i = 1, i <= Length[subdtotal], i++, 
 subopt = Append[
   subopt, {x /. FindMinimum[subdtotal[[i]], {x}, {y}][[2]], 
    y /. FindMinimum[subdtotal[[i]], {x}, {y}][[2]]}]]
subopt
```

[Creating Lists From Loops](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/creating-lists-from-loops)
[How do I find the Euclidean distance between one point and all the points in a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18929/how-do-i-find-the-euclidean-distance-between-one-point-and-all-the-points-in-a-l)

Comment: I think it should look something like                                             
 subsetdist = {}
For[i = 1, i <= Length[subdtotal], i++,
 subsetdist = 
  Append[subsetdist, {FindMinimum[subdtotal[[i]], {x}, {y}, [[1]]]}]]                    but I am really trying to get away from this For loop.

Comment: a bit aside but `NMinimize` works better here instead of `FindMinimum`

Comment: Thanks I will change them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace your `subopt` initialization and the `For` loop with:

```
subopt = {x, y} /. FindMinimum[#, {x}, {y}][[2]] & /@ subdtotal
```

Or using `Map` explicitly

```
{x, y} /. Map[FindMinimum[#, {x}, {y}][[2]] &, subdtotal]
```

Comment: Thank you that Map function replaces the loop very well. I was hoping to use the Nminimize function for the distance from each point in subopt to all points in preferences.