# Assign the output of a loop

Tags: list-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a table/Matrix during a For loop](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/creating-a-table-matrix-during-a-for-loop)

Yet another simple question.

```
For[i = 1, i < 3, i++,
 For[j = 1, j < 3, j++,
   Print[{i, j}]
 ]
]
```

I want to assign the output to a list, for example like:

```
tts = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}
```

All my efforts did not gave me the desired result, but I am sure it is possible. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have a look at `Table`.

Comment: ... and at the tutorial [Loops and control structures](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LoopsAndControlStructures.html)

Comment: if you _must_ use `For` loops: try `tts={};For[..., For[..., Print[{i,j}];AppendTo[tts,{i,j}]]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have some procedural style loop where you want to output things, you can often get quite good results using `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
 For[i = 1, i < 3, i++,
   For[j = 1, j < 3, j++,
     Sow[{i, j}]
   ]
 ]//Reap
 (* {Null, {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}}} *)
```

`Sow` stores the expression it's given and when `Reap` is called, it will return a list where the first element is the result of the expression it was given, and the second argument is a collection of all the elements that where sowed during evaluation of that expression. Much more complex interaction is available if you [look it up the doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html), and often you can solve problems in an entirely procedural style and then just reap the results at the end, and perhaps reformat it if that is desired.

Comment: thx jVincent, is there anyway to get rid of `Null` in the code, without doing it manually

Comment: @Darwin I'm not sure what you mean with manually. Normally if you are doing something where you only care about the sowed elements, you use `code//Reap//Last`.

Comment: i needed exactly that `Last` function! thx

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica tends to use print only for side effects. Also try to avoid the use of `For`.

You  can just use the result of table to the variable.

```
tts=Table[{i,j},{i,1,3},{j,1,3}];
```

If you want to look at the contents of `tts` just enter it into a cell and press shift+return.

Comment: hi, @ b.gatessucks and image_doctor , i would like to use `Table` but the code i have is bit complex, i am not sure if it is also possible with `Tabel` my `For-Loop` looks like this `For[p = 1, p < Length[lss] - 20,
 q = p;
 dx = lss[[q, 2]];
 ds = lss[[q, 3]];
 For[r = 1, ds <= dx,
   ds = ds + lss[[++q, 3]], r++] 
  Print[{lss[[p, 1]], lss[[q, 1]], 10*(lss[[p, 1]] - lss[[q, 1]])}]
   p++]`

Comment: @Darwin You should have started with your real problem / code, as long as it is not too long.