# LinePlot in For loop

Tags: plotting

I have the following Mathematica code to approximate Pi as inspired by the Matlab code in [George Zhao Ideas](http://quintessence823.blogspot.com/2013/01/monte-carlo-simulation-of-pi-with-matlab.html)

```
    n = 100000;
count = 0;
For[i = 0, i <= n, i++; 
 roll = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]; 
 count = count + 4 Sqrt[1 - roll^2];]
{count, n, count/n}
```

I tried to insert ListPlot in the For loop but failed.
My intention is to show how the {count/n} move per iteration. So, the ListPlot will get longer (approaching the Pi value) as the interation moves on.

Appreciate any help.

thanks.

Comment: `For` has no output, have a look at `Table`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a table/Matrix during a For loop](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/creating-a-table-matrix-during-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
n = 100;
count = 0;
pies = {count};
Dynamic[ListPlot[pies, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Pies will hold results as they are calculated. A dynamic ListPlot is drawn, it will be redrawn as For will be updating pies.

```
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
 roll = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
 count = count + 4 Sqrt[1 - roll^2];
 AppendTo[pies, count/i]; Pause[.05]]
```

Pause will pause each redraw for 5/100 second. Note that For loop has four parts separated by comma. Your last two parts, increment and body are not separated but joined in compound expression by a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I intended.

Comment: @mofai Cool. Some of the programming here is not very exemplary. Yet everything always has pedagogical value. :)

Answer (score 8):

You could use `Accumulate` to build a list of the successive totals:

```
n = 1000000;
rolls = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], {n}];
data = Accumulate[4 Sqrt[1 - rolls^2]] / Range[n];

ListLinePlot[data[[;; ;; 1000]], GridLines -> {None, {Pi}}, 
 PlotRange -> {3.13, 3.15}, DataRange -> {0, n}]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code but only the Axes and the Pi line are plotted. No data is plotted.

Comment: I see the line only if I change to `DataRange -> {0, n}`

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I only got the same chart as above after editing the last code to 
    ListLinePlot[data, GridLines -> {None, {Pi}}]

Comment: Thanks @cormullion, maybe it's a version thing. The shorthand works for me in 8.0.4

Answer (score 5):

It's more efficient to generate all random number in one go; one way is :

```
pi[n_] := Module[{roll = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], {n}]}, 
  Total[4 Sqrt[1 - roll^2] ]/n]

ListPlot[{#, pi[#]} & /@ Range[10000]]
```

Comment: thanks. This is very helpful for me