# Specifying an array that may have an unknown number of entries

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I'm running some process of unknown duration, and during the process, I need to periodically record the state of some variable.  If we knew exactly how long the process took, we could simply specify an array of appropriate size, and know that when the array is filled, we'll be finished.  However, if this is not the case, it seems one has to resort to operations like:

```
testArray = Append[testArray,dataPoint];
```

Which becomes both computationally intensive and memory intensive at the limit of large array sizes.  Is there a better way to proceed?  Or should I simply specify a very large version of `testArray` and then chop it down after I've finished my procedure and filled it to some limited extent?

Let me provide an example of the kind of process I'm thinking of (using the horrible `Append` strategy just to make things clear):

```
randVar=0;
storage={};

While[randVar<=0.99,
randVar=RandomReal[];
storage = Append[storage,randVar];
];
Length[storage];
```

How do we use e.g. Sow/Reap to deal with the array updates?

Comment: Just build a linked list, e.g., start with `myList={}`, then at each update do `myList={update,myList}`. You can flatten/manipulate as needed to collect to final result. Or, use `Sow` and `Reap`.

Comment: @rasher Great, do you know which method is fastest?

Comment: @rasher And how can I avoid nesting behavior?  Should I flatten at every step or just not worry about this?  It seems wasteful.  And does repeatedly applying Flatten lead to a slowdown?

Comment: Probably `Sow/Reap`, but not a huge difference. For your question, `Sow/Reap` makes the most sense. As far as the second query, whenever possible, do list operations as one, so one flatten will beat repeated.

Comment: @rasher If you wouldn't mind, could you show me an example of using Sow/Reap?  I'm reading through the manual now, and I'm not 100% sure I know what you have in mind.

Comment: Will post as answer...

Comment: @rasher I appreciate your time!

Comment: You may find this answer useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2971/121

Comment: Actually, after reading both questions I have decided to close this one as a duplicate.  (It and its answers will remain.)  If anyone disagrees with this please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Sow` and `Reap`. Here's a contrived example:

```
{result, reaped} = Reap[Map[(Sow[#]; #!) &, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

So, we are going through the list of numbers 1 to 5, computing factorial. We want the result, and what the number was. The `Sow` puts each into the queue as we do our work, the `Reap` gets the results, along with whatever was `Sown`. If you removed the `Reap`, just the results come back. Quite useful for debugging!

*Very* powerful construct, I urge you to study it, it has flexibility such as labeling items, etc. and is quite fast and cheap on resources.

Per your update:

```
randVar = 0

{nothing, storage} = 
  Reap[While[randVar <= 0.99, randVar = RandomReal[];
     Sow[randVar]];];

Length[storage[[1]]]
```

Note that if something like this example is really what you're doing, *much* more efficient to generate variates in bulk and grab until criteria is met:

```
storage = TakeWhile[RandomReal[1, 1000000], # <= .99 &]
```

Comment: This is actually quite cool.  However, how would I use this to periodically enter an unspecified number of data points into an array structure of flexible size?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your original question - if so, I'll delete my answer, but that is *precisely* what `Sow` and `Reap` do. Are you implying you need to examine the array contents *during* the process? If so, making a linked-list is a more plausible solution.

Comment: Probably this is just me being slow, let me provide an example...

Comment: I provided an example of what I meant in the question posting.

Comment: @110110: see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `var = Append[var, element]` you can use `AppendTo[var,element]` which is a little bit terser, but not less intensive. Indeed it is recommended to use `Sow` and `Reap` instead of `Append`/`AppendTo`. A third option would be to use [linked lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/731) since with that method you do not copy the entire list every time and so it does not have the same problems as `Append` does. `Append` basically makes a copy of the list to add something to it. At the end you can simply flatten the list to get it the way you want it. For example:

```
randVar = 0;
storage = {};
While[randVar <= .99,
 randVar = RandomReal[];
 storage = {randVar, storage};
 ]
Flatten@storage
```