# counting number of outputs in For loop

Tags: procedural-programming

I am using `For` loop and `If` within it. For example:

```
For[a=0, a < 21, a = a + 1,
 If[EvenQ[a], Print[a,"\n"]]
]
```

Certainly, the program will print all even numbers below 21 starting from 0.
I would like to `Print` the output along with counting number, like:

```
1. 0 
2. 2
3. 4
```

etc.

I will be glad if you suggest me some command for the same.

Comment: A good programming language offers a step width different from 1 in a for loop.
For[a=0, a < 21, a = a +2,
You will not need If[EvenQ[a] then.

Comment: I agree with you. But I need this counting in a more involved program. Thanx btw.

Comment: @J. M. Thank you for editing it look much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i = 1;
For[a = 0, a < 21, a = a + 1, If[EvenQ[a], Print[i++, ". ", a]]]
```

> 1. 0
> 2. 2
> 3. 4

(and so on)

Another style of coding for your consideration:

```
Cases[Range[0, 21], _?EvenQ]

TableForm[%, TableHeadings -> Automatic]
```

See also [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html), e.g. [Creating a table/Matrix during a For loop](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/creating-a-table-matrix-during-a-for-loop/2971#2971)

Comment: I would have used `Select[Range[0, 21], EvenQ]` instead.

Comment: Why not cut to the chase: `Range[0, 21, 2]`?

Comment: @Michael, that would have corresponded to the OP using `a += 2` in his/her loop.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, that's cleaner.  On the other hand `_?EvenQ` introduces the concept of pattern matching which may serve the OP.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I fear that would reduce the contrived example a bit too much to be instructive.

Comment: @J.M. On a pragmatic level, that seems a difference without a distinction.  If there is more going on in the OP's actual loop, then all the `Cases`/`Select`/`Range` approaches are insufficient. One might use `Map` + `Range`, though.  --  Mr.W., I suppose it depends on the lesson. In my mind, I think the OP either oversimplified the problem or is looking for the easiest way to do exactly what is asked. `TableHeadings -> Automatic` taught me something, so +1 for that. :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your answer, i++, fits my line of thinking and am using it in my code. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user31694 You are welcome.  If this answer fully satisfies your requirements please consider [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest reading this Q and A: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica) as it is instructive and useful.

Just some variants  to illustrate `Sow` and `Reap` and `MapIndexed`:

```
Reap[(i = 1; 
    For[a = 0, a < 21, If[EvenQ@a, Sow[{i++, a}]]; a = a + 1])][[-1, 
   1]] // TableForm
```

or

```
(i = 1); Range[0, 21] /. {x_?EvenQ :> {i++, x}, 
   x_?OddQ :> Sequence[]} // TableForm
```

or

```
MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, Range[0, 21, 2]] // TableForm
```

There are many ways to do things. That is part of the fun.

Comment: Also `i = 1; Cases[Range[0, 21], x_?EvenQ :> {i++, x}] // TableForm`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  thank you, yes...I only posted really to illustrate Reap and Sow for this example as well as hyperlink to loop alternatives...and some ways to 'count'...like your comment:)