# Fastest way to test if a numerical array has complex elements

Tags: performance-tuning, pattern-matching, packed-arrays

I am looking for the fastest way to test whether an *n*-dimensional numerical (`NumericQ`) array (in the `ArrayQ` sense) is complex or not.  It is considered complex if it has at least one complex element.

It is an important requirement that this test must not unpack packed arrays.

Currently I have `Not@ArrayQ[arr, _, FreeQ[#, _Complex] &]`, which does not unpack, but it executes the test for each element of packed arrays (can be tested using `Print`).  Theoretically it's sufficient to test only one: all elements of a packed array are necessarily of the same type.  In theory it's possible to detect whether an array is packed, and if it is, only test the first element, but this is very ugly, so I'd like to avoid it.  It' also not easy to implement for an *n*-dimensional array.

What I am hoping for is a function which is internally special cased for packed arrays and is thus very fast.

Comment: Something like `PackedArrayQ[arr, Complex] || Not@ArrayQ[arr, _, FreeQ[#, _Complex] &]` (I don't know how to check if `PackedArrayQ` unpacks and/or tests each element) Edit: *Needs["Developer`"]*

Comment: @ssch I didn't know about the second argument of PackedArrayQ.  Perhaps something like ``Deverloper`PackedArrayQ[arr, Complex] || (Not@Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr] && Not@FreeQ[arr, Complex])``.  Care to post an answer?

Comment: What exactly would be a compex array? One in which every element belongs to Complexes, no matter if they are real or integers, but at least one of them is actually a complex? Or any array with at least one Complex element? Or all complex elements? Your test seems to define it as an array in which at least one of its elements has a complex subelement. Is that the idea?

Comment: @Rojo Okay, clarifications:  the array is guaranteed to be numeric (as in `NumericQ`).  If it has at least one complex element, it is considered to be complex.  This is why I had `Not@ ... FreeQ` instead of `MemberQ`.  Use case: need to decide how to transfer the data through MathLink so it's easy to handle in C on the other side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One potential problem with directly testing the complete list using `` Developer`PackedArray[arr_, type_] `` is that this test may fail if the whole array is not packed, but sub-arrays are. As a result, one can too easily fall through to the more general test using `FreeQ` (or `MemberQ`) and end up unpacking anyway. This can be avoided by using `ReplaceAll` to remove packed arrays in advance of the membership test, which is a trick I also used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/#2919).

For present purposes, we might write:

```
ClearAll[containsComplexesQ];
containsComplexesQ[expr_] := MemberQ[
  expr /. {
     l_List /; Developer`PackedArrayQ[l, Complex] &&
                Return[True, containsComplexesQ] -> Null, 
     l_List /; Developer`PackedArrayQ[l] -> Null
    }, _Complex, -1
  ];
```

Now:

```
On["Packing"];
testArray = {RandomReal[1, 10], RandomComplex[1 + I, 10]};

containsComplexesQ[testArray]
(* -> True *)
```

An important difference between `MemberQ` and `FreeQ` is that the former has `Heads -> False`, while the latter has `Heads -> True` by default. Although one may of course specify `Heads -> True` to mimic the behavior of the example given in the question, since the intended application is to test array-like expressions, it's just as well to leave the default as it is. Furthermore, it's sufficient for the purpose of determining whether any complex values are present to test only level -1 of the structure, rather than every level as `FreeQ` does by default. As a result, a judicious use of `MemberQ` as above may perform somewhat better than `Composition[Not, FreeQ]` by virtue of testing fewer subexpressions.

Comment: But why not exit e.g. through exception throwing upon the first case where ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[l, Complex]`` woul d give `True`? It should be generally faster than either of the options you mentioned.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin very good point! I added it.

Comment: @OleksandrR. A nice use of `Return` - this version did not occur to me here.

Comment: I see that you are using `And` for flow control as Simon Woods did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7820/121).  Is that something you often do?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard not usually, but I'm not averse to it either. It seemed within the spirit of a `Condition`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Is there a reason why this use of `Return` is not documented (except on the refpage on `Return::nofunc`)?

Comment: @sebhofer I think mostly historical. There are a number of functions which reside in a "gray area", in the sense that they are widely used (also by internal code), yet not documented. But `Return` stands out since it is a public function, while most of those I meant are in ``Internal` `` , ``Developer` `` and such like. So, having it documented would be nice.

Answer (score 9):

In the Developer Utilities Package there's a function [`PackedArrayQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Developer/ref/PackedArrayQ.html) that checks if an expression is a packed array, optionally of a certain type.

This can be combined with the previous test:

```
ComplexArrayQ[arr_]:=Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr, Complex] ||
           (Not@Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr] && Not@FreeQ[arr, Complex])

arr = RandomComplex[1 + I, {500, 10}];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr, Complex] (* True *)
arr[[3,1;;4]]=I;
Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr, Complex] (* False *)
ComplexArrayQ@arr                    (* True *)
```