# What does IndexBy do and how exactly does it work?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, undocumented

I just saw the function `IndexBy` in the autocomplete suggestions and I was curious to know exactly how it works. Unfortunately, [there's no trace of it in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=IndexBy). It returns [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) objects, so it must be new (or recently refurbished) in version 10.0.2

What does this function do are what syntax does it require? Does it have further perks that are not immediately obvious?

> **Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, as an undocumented function this was liable to be removed. And, indeed, it has been removed from version 10.1.0. The good thing is, if anyone needs a function like this, there's now kguler and Mr. Wizard's implementations to choose from.

Comment: if it is not documented, then it is not meant to be used at user level. It might be a place holder for future version.

Comment: Related [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18926/3066)

Comment: @Nasser If it is indeed not meant to be used at user level, I'm curious about why it shows up in the autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: @episanty, I think all system symbols will show up in the autocomplete suggestions, though many are undocumented. For a complete list of such symbols: `Select[Names["*"],MatchQ[ToExpression[#<>"::usage"],_MessageName]&]` (it takes a minute to run).

Comment: Note that IndexBy will be removed in a future version of Mathematica. It was something that was considered for 10.0.0 but didn't make the cut.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
?? *`*IndexBy*
```

> [image]

Following  the usual `spelunking` steps

```
ClearAttributes[IndexBy, {Protected, ReadProtected}]
?? IndexBy
```

reveals the code that defines `IndexBy`. Simplifying (and ignoring argument type-checks) it is something like:

```
indexBy[f_][expr_]:=Association[(f[#]->#)&/@If[AssociationQ[expr],Values[expr],expr]]

indexBy[foo][Range[5]]
(* <|foo[1]->1,foo[2]->2,foo[3]->3,foo[4]->4,foo[5]->5|> *)

indexBy[foo][<|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z|>]
(* <|foo[x]->x,foo[y]->y,foo[z]->z|> *)
```

Answer (score 11):

Observing the code reported in kguler's answer I note that it could be written more efficiently, if such an operation is desired.  Specifically `(f[#]->#)&` cannot be compiled because the result is a `Rule`.  It would be better to map `f` directly to the values, then use [`AssociationThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html) to construct the association.

### Proposal

```
indexBy[f_][expr_] := expr ~indexBy~ f

indexBy[asc_Association, f_] := Values[asc] ~indexBy~ f

p : indexBy[expr_, f_] /;
  ! AtomQ[expr] || Message[indexBy::normal, 1, HoldForm @ p] := 
    AssociationThread[f /@ expr, expr]

p : indexBy[_, _, __] /; 
  Message[indexBy::argt, indexBy, Length @ Unevaluated @ p, 1, 2] := Null
```

### Timings

```
expr = Range[1*^6];
f = #^2 &;

IndexBy[expr, f] // AbsoluteTiming // First
indexBy[expr, f] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.353077
>
> 0.404023
> ```

```
expr = AssociationThread @@ RandomReal[9, {2, 1*^6}];
f = Round;

IndexBy[expr, f] // AbsoluteTiming // First
indexBy[expr, f] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.122064
>
> 0.372021
> ```

Comment: I just ran into this and had a question. On 10.1, the `AtomQ` version is placed above `indexBy[expr_, f_]` in the `DownValues`. So, that `index[5, f]` returns `AssociationThread[5, 5]`. This can be fixed by using `indexBy[expr : Except[_?AtomQ, _], f_]`, but I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do. Any thoughts.

Comment: @rcollyer I read your message before and thought "okay, when I get v10.1 I'll fix this" but now that I am running 10.1 I realize this has nothing to do with version and everything to do with a poorly conceived definition.  Feel free to be more blunt about my stupid mistakes next time!

Comment: I didn't realize it was your mistake. I was just playing with it, broke it, and tried to fix it. Next time, do better. :D

Comment: @rcollyer By the way what do you think of the `||` form in the answer now?  It is my attempt at using Simon's flow control from [(7820)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7820/121).  Do you make use of such things yourself now?  (You expressed interest below that post.)