# Splitting a list into increasing sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of numbers (say, for example, `{1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2}`), and I want to split it into sublists so that each sublist is the (smallest) sublist whose sum is larger than the preceding one. For the above example, my desired output is `{{1},{2},{3},{4},{3,2},{1,2,3},{4,3},{2}}` (the sums are `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`, and the `{2}` at the end just uses the remaining leftover elements).

Neither `Split` nor `SplitBy` seems to be able to do what I need. Is there a primitive to do this, or would someone care to invent a clever function?

Comment: How about showing what you've tried? (this is trivial to do...)

Comment: Well, the only thing I've tried is a complicated solution involving keeping track of the current sum and the tail of the list and using that to find the next greater head.

Comment: I still think it's worth putting in what you've tried. Some here (me included, actually, but not everyone) like to see the effort that people have put into solving their problem. It could be that what you've tried is the right way to do it, but it just needs a little tweak. In correcting it, a couple of things can happen: you can learn a little more about MMA syntax, you can learn some coding tricks, you can better prepare for [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users](pitfalls), other users can learn from the post, etc

Comment: @march Fair enough. To be honest, I was hoping I was just missing something in SplitBy, or that another primitive would do the trick, and I wouldn't have to write anything.

Comment: How big will the lists be? Is performance important (the methods so far can be handily beaten if it is), or will list be so small it does not matter?

Comment: Performance is not particularly important. You can assume the list will have under 1000 elements.

Comment: @ciao But an elegant solution is always preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2};

f = Module[{b, c, d, n},
    b = {{First[#]}};
    c = Rest[#];
    Catch[
     While[True,
      n = 1; While[Total[d = Quiet@Check[Take[c, n],
            Throw[AppendTo[b, c]]]] <= Total@Last[b], n++];
      AppendTo[b, d];
      c = Drop[c, n]]];
    b] &;

f[a]
```

> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 3}, {2}}

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. That's along the lines of what I was thinking in my comment above, but done more elegantly than I would probably have written it. I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve explicit loops.

Comment: I think the `Catch` and inner `While` can be replaced by the following, which completely avoids an inner loop:
`While[Length@c > 0,
   d = Accumulate@c;
   n = Max@FirstPosition[d, x_ /; x > Total@Last@b, Length@d];
   b = Append[b, Take[c, n]];
   c = Drop[c, n]];`

Comment: @Xavier - quite right. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a purely functional solution (i.e. not using mutable state), based in `FoldList` (since the one based on linked lists has been already taken):

```
stepF = 
  Function @ With[{sum = First @ #1 + #2, len = #[[2]], prevsum = #1[[3]]},
    If[sum > prevsum, {0, 0, sum, len + 1}, {sum, len + 1, prevsum, 0}]
  ];

getLengths[lst_List] :=
  DeleteCases[0] @ Append[#, Length[lst] - Total[#]] & @
     FoldList[stepF, {0, 0, 0, 0}, lst][[All, -1]];

splitInc[lst_] := Internal`PartitionRagged[lst, getLengths[lst]]
```

For example:

```
splitInc[lst]

(* {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 3}, {2}} *)
```

The idea is to use `FoldList` to determine the lengths of all sublists, and then split. At every iteration in `FoldList` the function `stepF` takes a list of 4 elements `{currentSum, currentLength, previousSum, splitLengthOrZero}` as a first argument, and a next element of the original list as a second argument, and returns a modified list of 4 elements - working basically as a state machine. We then just have to pick those states where the last element (`splitLengthOrZero`) is non-zero, and we get a list of lengths.  In place of `` Internal`PartitionRagged `` one could also use Mr.Wizard's `dynP`.

Comment: @Xavier Thanks. Glad you liked it. You can search the site for `dynP` function of Mr.Wizard, which has comparable performance to ``Internal`PartitionRagged``, while being implemented purely in top-level code.

Comment: Neat, but fails when negatives present. +1 though. Interestingly, dramatic slowdown with reals.

Comment: @ciao Thanks. It does work with negative numbers, for me. Can you provide an example where it fails for you? Re: slowdown - indeed. Probably related to the auto-compilation, although I still don't understand why - by default the arguments of compiled function are anyway reals.

Comment: @ciao One guess would be that, for integers, the list of 4 elements produced at each iteration of `Fold`, can still be packed, and is packed since `Fold` auto-compiles. For reals, the list contains 2 integers and 2 reals, and so can't be packed. Not sure if I am right, but I can't see any better explanation at the moment. One thing that kind of confirms my guess is that if you use `N@{0, 0, 0, 0}` as a starting value in `FoldList`, instead of `{0, 0, 0, 0}`, then the performance on integers also degrades just like it does for reals.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Range[-3,3] trivial example - s/b 7 distinct sets, but output is just the range...

Comment: @ciao This is not an error per se. The initial value of  the sum, which the sum of elements in the first sublist of the result must be larger than, has not been  specified by the OP. I took it to be zero. In this interpretation, the answer is right. Alternatative interpretation is that it it e.g. `-Infinity` (or, simply, any number smaller than the first element). The problem is simply underspecified in this respect.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Fair enough (depends on the what definition of "is" is, eh? ;-} ) - btw -cool way to do this for large lists is via bin search - quite fast...

Comment: @ciao You got me intrigued - how would you apply a binary search to this problem?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Shall I spoil the ending, or do you want the "ah-ha!" yourself? Hint: Look at the pattern of positions in the accumulation of the target list vs where the subset breaks happen...

Comment: @ciao As much as I'd like to solve this puzzle, I can't afford taking any more time from other things I need to take care of, at the moment. I did actually look at the accumulated original list before asking you, but I guess my pattern-recognition skills got seriously worse in the few last years. But the one thing that really stopped me from looking in that direction initially was that we can't exclude negative elements in the list, in which case accumulated list will not be necessarily  sorted, and so binary search can't be used. But I see the direction of thought.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27558/discussion-between-ciao-and-leonid-shifrin).

Answer (score 5):

A bit more concise, seems at least as fast as those posted so far:

```
setter[list_] := Module[{fs = 0, t = First@list - 1, f, u},
   f[x_] := If[(fs += x) > t, t = fs; fs = 0; True, False];
   u = Union[Pick[Range@Length@list, f /@ list], {Length@list}];
   MapThread[list[[#1 ;; #2]] &, {Prepend[Most@u, 0] + 1, u}]];
```

Comment: Voted it up without testing, but I guess `target` should be `list`?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin : oops, yep, Fixing...

Answer (score 5):

### Split

With a special test function as the second argument `Split` does give the desired result:

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Module[{s = 0, t = 0}, Split[#, Or[(s += #) < t, t = s; s = 0] &]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
f @ {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2}
```

> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 3}, {2}}

```
lst = RandomInteger[9, 10]
```

> {{1, 0, 8, 7, 7, 5, 3, 6, 8,  0}

```
f @ lst
```

> {{1}, {0, 8}, {7, 7}, {5, 3, 6}, {8, 0}}}

See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7820/125) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105800/125) for the origin of `Or` trick.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another possible solution:

```
mySorting[{}, _] := {};

mySorting[list_, sum_] := 
  Block[{firstelem = First@list, listlength = Length@list,tempsum, poselem = 1},
   tempsum = firstelem;
   While[tempsum <= sum && poselem + 1 <= listlength, 
        tempsum = tempsum + list[[poselem++ + 1]]];
   {list[[Range@poselem]], Sequence @@ mySorting[Drop[list, poselem], tempsum]}];

mySorting[list_] := 
  With[{firstelem = First@list}, 
  {{firstelem}, Sequence @@ mySorting[Rest@list, firstelem]}];
```

For your example `list = {1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2}` we get

```
mySorting[list]
{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 3}, {2}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another answer:

```
pos[list_] := Module[{currcounter = 0, currmax = 0},
   Map[(
    currcounter += #;
    If[currcounter > currmax, 
        currmax = currcounter; 
        currcounter = 0;
        False,
      currcounter += #;
       True]) &, 
    list]]

g[list_] := 
 With[{arr = pos[list]},
  With[{splitpos = Split[arr, #1 == True &]},
   ReplacePart[splitpos, 
    Rule @@@ Transpose@{Position[splitpos, True | False], list}]
  ]]
```

`pos[{1,2,3,4,3,2,1}]` is `{False, False, False, False, True, False, True}`, with `True` in any position that is not the end of a required sub-list. The function `g` then `Split`s that list, so as to get a resulting list of exactly the right shape but with `False` and `True` instead of the required list elements. Finally, we insert the list elements.

Comment: The output starts `{{1, 2} ...}` but it should be `{{1}, {2} ...}`.

Comment: Thanks, I must have been asleep there. There's an irritating reason why that's true.

Comment: @Xavier, this whole approach is badly flawed because `SplitBy` evaluates the function once for every pair of adjacent elements. Under the hood, it's just calling `Split`, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid happening. I was expecting it just to evaluate the function at each element, and then split according to that list.

Comment: @Chris Algorithm now fixed. Slightly different method.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a very rough-and-ready one which uses [linked lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica/25474#25474):

```
toLinkedList = Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Reverse@#]&;
r[list_, currval_, currans_, curransval_] := 
 r[list[[2]], currval, {list[[1]], currans}, curransval + list[[1]]]
r[{}, c_, a_, v_] := a
r[list_, currval_, currans_, curransval_] /; curransval > currval := 
 {currans, r[list, curransval, {}, 0]}

partition[list_] := r[toLinkedList[list], 0, {}, 0]
```

Output:

```
{{1, {}}, {{2, {}}, {{3, {}}, {{4, {}}, {{2, {3, {}}}, {{3, {2, {1, {}}}}, {{3, {4, {}}}, {2, {}}}}}}}}}
```

which is linked-list speak for

```
{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {3,2}, {1,2,3}, {4,3}, {2}}
```

Comment: … although de-linked-listing it is more than my tired brain wants to handle at the moment, since `Flatten` won't work, being a linked list of linked lists.

Comment: Here's a silly way: `Flatten@*First /@ 
  Drop[NestWhileList[Last@# &, output, Length@# == 2 &], -1] /. 
 HoldPattern[Flatten[s_?AtomQ]] :> {s}`.

Comment: Or: `Drop[#, -1] & /@ Internal'PartitionRagged[#, Differences@Join[{0}, Flatten@Position[#, ll[]]]] &@ Flatten@(output /. {} -> ll[])`

Comment: This is better than the first (sorry if I'm being annoying; I'm just interested in how to do this): `Flatten@*First /@ NestList[Last@# &, output, Count[output, {}, Infinity] - 1]/. HoldPattern[Flatten[s_?AtomQ]] :> {s} `.

Comment: I have explained in a linked post, what to do when your elements are themselves lists - section named "Generalized linked lists". You have to use a symbolic container like `ll` (or any other symbol) instead of `List`, and then use `Flatten` with 3 args. I am a bit surprised that you didn't see that, given that you provided a link to that post. In any case, linked lists were the first thing that also came to my mind when I read the question.

Comment: @Leonid That involves making different heads for each linked list, does it not? I was tired and didn't want to think any harder.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Yes, you are right. You pick a symbol which becomes the head of the linked list "cons cell", and in case when you work with several linked lists at the same time, you will indeed generally have to pick different symbols for them. In practice, however, it is pretty rare to have more than two linked lists interacting with each other at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I also thought immediatly about the `Fold` function using the `#1` and `#2` arguments of it. Here is my try:

Given the OP list:

```
mylist = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2}
```

then:

(*for versions<10.2 replace `Nothing` with `Sequence[]`*):

```
foo = (If[(sn = #2 + Tr@Last@#1) > s, s = sn; lst = {}, 
     lst = Nothing]; {Sequence @@ Most@#1, Join[Last@#1, {#2}], lst}) &;

Fold[foo, {{s = First@mylist}, {}}, Rest@mylist]
```

> `{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 3}, {2}}`

Comment: I tested and it seems my solution performs slower than the others ... At least it is short code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
splitInc[list_List]:=Block[{i=0,previousTotal=0,current={}},
    Last@Reap@Scan[
        (
        AppendTo[current,#];
        If[Total[current] > previousTotal
            ,Sow[#,i];previousTotal=Total[current];current={};i++
            ,Sow[#,i]]
        )&
        , list
    ]
]
splitInc[list]
```

> {{1},{2},{3},{4},{3,2},{1,2,3},{4,3},{2}}