# Function to create a path made of horizontal and vertical lines between a number of points

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I would like to create a function where I can define which case I want to use to create a path.

```
p1 = {40, 48}; p2 = {50, 116}; p3 = {63, 160};
listPurple = Symbol["p" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[3];
disksPurple = {Purple, Disk[#, 2] & /@ listPurple};
Graphics[{disksPurple}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image: Imagem]

I do not want two functions, as I created:

```
lVertical[p1_, p2_] := {p1, {p1[[1]], p2[[2]]}};
lHorizontal[p1_, p2_] := {p1, {p2[[1]], p1[[2]]}};
```

With them I define whether it will be a horizontal or vertical line:

```
l1 = lVertical[p1, p2];
l2 = lHorizontal[p2, p1];
l3 = lHorizontal[p2, p3];
l4 = lVertical[p3, p2];
lines = Sort@Symbol["l" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[4];
l = {Red, Dashed, Line[#] & /@ lines};
Graphics[{l, disksPurple}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image: Imagem]

I would like it in a format similar to this:

```
f[p1_, p2_, lVertical or lHorizontal]
```

Comment: @corey979 I did not know this function. I'll try to use it.

Comment: I initially suggested `AnglePath`, but after playing with it in combination with `Projection`, `UnitVector`s etc., it turned out to be to cumbersome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Function:**

```
path[points_List, directions_List] := 
 Block[{disksPurple, pseudoCross, v, h, ints, dirs},
  If[Length@directions != Length@points - 1, Print["incorrect input"]; Abort[]];
  disksPurple = {Purple, Disk[#, 2] & /@ points};
  pseudoCross[p1_, p2_] := {{p1[[1]], p2[[2]]}, {p2[[1]], p1[[2]]}};
  dirs = directions /. {v -> {1, 0}, h -> {0, 1}};
  ints = Flatten[#, 1] & @ Pick[pseudoCross @@@ Partition[points, 2, 1], dirs, 1];
  Graphics[{disksPurple, {Red, Dashed, Line @ Riffle[points, ints]}}]
  ]
```

**Usage:** list of points is the first argument; the second is a list of directions (only *first* directions) between the consecutive points. E.g., to go from `p1` to `p2` first vertically, and then horizontally, type `v`; to go first horizontally, then vertically - type `h`. The reason is that if you go vertically from `p1`, you have to go horizontally next to reach `p2`, and *vice versa*.

**Examples:**

```
Clear[p1, p2, p3, p4, pts]
p1 = {40, 48}; p2 = {50, 116}; p3 = {63, 160}; p4 = {80, 100};
pts = {p1, p2, p3, p4};

path[pts, {v, v, v}]
```

[image]

```
path[pts, {h, h, h}]
```

[image]

```
path[pts, {v, h, h}]
```

[image]

```
path[pts, {v, h, v}] (* this is correct, just the choice of direction is poor *)
```

[image]

---

```
n = 10;
pts = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {n, 2}];
dir = RandomChoice[{v, h}, Length@pts - 1];

path[pts, dir]
```

[image]

Works also when three consecutive points have their $x$ or $y$ coordinates the same:

```
path[{{100, 0}, {200, 0}, {300, 0}}, {h, h}]
```

[image]

The same image is obtained with `{v, v}`, `{v, h}` and `{h, v}`; similarly for the vertical alignment.

---

Incorrect input:

```
path[{{100, 0}, {200, 0}, {300, 0}}, {h, h, v}]
```

> incorrect input
>
> $Aborted

---

And finally, there's this funny behaviour when you make a typo in the `directions`:

```
Clear[p1, p2, p3, p4, pts, path]
p1 = {40, 48}; p2 = {50, 116}; p3 = {63, 160}; p4 = {80, 100};
pts = {p1, p2, p3, p4};
path[pts, {v, v, hv}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here is an attempt at automatically finding the best paths to use to join the points.
This avoids having to explicitly give the horizontal and vertical specification for every point.

```
ClearAll[generateDirections, hvPath]

generateDirections[pts_, initialDirection_] :=
 Module[{d = initialDirection /. None :> RandomChoice[{1, 2}]},
  Join[{d},
   (Ordering[#[[All, d = 3 - d]]][[2]] == 2 || (d = 3 - d); d) & /@ 
    Partition[pts, 3, 1]]
 ]

hvPath[{pt1 : {a_, b_}, pt2 : {i_, j_}}, dir_] :=
  {pt1, Switch[dir, 1, {i, b}, 2, {a, j}], pt2}

hvPath[pts : {{_, _} ..}, initialDirection_ : None] :=
 Join @@ MapThread[
   hvPath, {Partition[pts, 2, 1], generateDirections[pts, initialDirection]}]
```

The idea is to use `generateDirections` to generate the best horizontal-vertical pathways, using the rule of thumb of initiating every new path using alternativily horizontal and vertical lines, except when this results in going over the same line used to arrive to the given point.
Once the optimal directions are found the rest is easily handled by `hvPath` which generates the list with all the middle points.

Here is a couple of usage example:

```
With[{pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}},
 Graphics[{
   PointSize@0.02, Point@pts,
   Dashed, Line@hvPath@pts
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

and a more complex one in which we join 20 random points:

[image]

Comment: I believe your code would benefit from refactoring.  If I do that may I edit your post to use my code (which you can revert if you do not like) or would you prefer that I post a separate answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sure, suit yourself! I figured there should have been a much better way to write more concisely the conditions, and everything else. Show me your best one-liner! :P

Comment: When I have time I'll give it my best shot! ;^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard awesome. Very interesting stuff. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, and I am glad you like it.  My use of `Or` (`||`) here is quite unusual as far as I know; I learned the use of Boolean operators for programmatic flow control from Simon Woods in post [(7820)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7820/121).  At first I found that usage opaque but after I understood it and started using it I actually really like it and find that it is not opaque and can even read more easily than If/Then/Else logic if used carefully.

Comment: if you mean the use of `a or b` as a `if not a then b`, I can't say I had seen it before in Mathematica (except in the answer you linked), but it is a pretty commonly used technique in many other languages (bash being the first that comes to mind). I agree that Its use here makes for a rather elegant solution to the problem though.

Comment: Yes, I did mean that, and I shall profess my ignorance and admit I haven't seen elsewhere because I really only know *Mathematica*.  On the one hand I know a broader exposure would prevent this kind of "myopia" but on the other my memory is poor and I fear forgetting what I know now trying to learn other languages.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply provide two definitions for `f`

```
f[p1_, p2_, lVertical] := {p1, {p1[[1]], p2[[2]]}}
f[p1_, p2_, lHorizontal] := {p1, {p2[[1]], p1[[2]]}}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[f, pathF]
f[dir : v | h][p1_, p2_] := Module[{d = dir /. {v -> 2, h -> 1},
     mid = {{p1[[1]], p2[[2]]}, {p2[[1]], p1[[2]]}}}, {p1, mid[[3 - d]], p2}];

pathF[p_List, dir_List] := Join@@(f[#2][## & @@ #]&@@@ Transpose[{Partition[p, 2, 1], dir}])

pts = {{40, 48}, {50, 116}, {63, 160}, {80, 100}};
Grid[Partition[#, 4]] &@(ListPlot[pathF[##], Joined -> True, 
       Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[#]}, 
       PlotLabel -> #2] &[pts, #] & /@ Tuples[{v, h}, 3])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
points = RandomReal[{-50, 50}, {8, 2}];
dirs = RandomChoice[{v, h}, 7];
ListPlot[pathF[##], Joined -> True, PlotLabel -> #2, Axes -> False,  
   Epilog -> {PointSize[.05], Opacity[.5, Red], Point@#, 
     Opacity[1, Black], MapIndexed[Text[Style[#2[[1]], 16], #] &, #]}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 5] &[points, dirs]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Quick Draw (for an alternative way to do the job using some unknown MMA functionality)

```
n=10;
pts= RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];

ListLinePlot[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> Purple, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Different formation can be created by considering different arrangement

```
pts1 = pts[[RandomSample[Range[n], n]]];
ListLinePlot[pts1, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> Full, 
MeshStyle -> Purple, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
p1 = {40, 48}; p2 = {50, 116}; p3 = {63, 160};
listPurple = Symbol["p" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[3];
disksPurple = {Purple, Disk[#, 2] & /@ listPurple};
Graphics[{disksPurple}, ImageSize -> 200];

fLine[p1_, p2_, case_] := 
 If[TrueQ[case == v], {p1, {p1[[1]], p2[[2]]}}, {p1, {p2[[1]], 
    p1[[2]]}}]

l1 = fLine[p1, p2, v];
l2 = fLine[p2, p1, h];
l3 = fLine[p2, p3, h];
l4 = fLine[p3, p2, v];
lines = Sort@Symbol["l" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[4];
l = {Red, Dashed, Line[#] & /@ lines};
Graphics[{l, disksPurple}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

This part you choose cases:

`fLine[p1_, p2_, case_] := 
     If[TrueQ[case == v], {p1, {p1[[1]], p2[[2]]}}, {p1, {p2[[1]], 
        p1[[2]]}}]`