# What are some general strategies to avoid using For loops?

Tags: programming, functional-style, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica)

While there [are some cases where a `For` loop might be reasonable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2158/8), it's a general mantra – one I subscribe to myself – that "if you are using a `For` loop in Mathematica, you are probably doing it wrong". But `For` and `Do` loops are familiar to people who already know other programming languages. It is common for new Mathematica users to rely on loop constructs, only to become frustrated with performance or code complexity.

> My question is: **are there some general rules of thumb that would help new users select the appropriate alternative to a procedural `For` or `Do` loop, and are there other useful Mathematica constructs, aside from `RandomVariate`/`Nest`/`Fold`/`Inner`/`Outer`/`Tuples` that they should know about in order to avoid those loops?**