# Problems with For statement

Tags: functions, warning-messages

I'm trying to iterate some expression through for loop:

```
 a = 0; b = 0.1; ϵ = 0.01; Ns = 100;
 lhr[t_] := Normal[Series[-k7 x[t] y[t] /. Nsol /. initConst, {t, 0, Ns}]][[1]]; lhr[t]
 rhr1[t_] := Normal[Series[-k7 x[t] y[t] /. Nsol /. initConst, {t, 0, Ns}]][[1]]; rhr1[t]
 h = 0.01
 For[t = a, t < b, t += h; 
   If[Abs[lhr[t]] < ϵ*Max[Abs[rhr1[t]]], Print[t]]]
```

I'm getting following errors:

> General::ivar: 0.01` is not a valid variable. >>
>   General::ivar: 0.01` is not a valid variable. >>
>   General::ivar: 0.01` is not a valid variable. >>
>   General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Can you help with this problem?

Comment: Please include *complete* code (what are`Nsol`,`initConst`?). In any case, the `;` in the `For` is incorrect.

Comment: Hi wizar and welcome to Mathematica.SE. Don't set `h` outside the `For` loop. It's causing a clash.

Comment: the ivar error is not in the `For` loop, but in `Series`. You need to use some other variable for the series expansion, then substitute the numeric value of t:  `Normal[Series[ f[x] ,{x,0,Ns}]] /. x->t `

Comment: `For[t = a, t < b, t += h; If[Abs[lhr[t]] < ϵ Max[Abs[rhr1[t]]], Print[t]]]` should be `For[t = a, t < b, t += h, If[Abs[lhr[t]] < ϵ Max[Abs[rhr1[t]]], Print[t]]]`; that is, comma not semicolon after `h`.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned two important points:

- you really should provide a working example
- your problem is actually not really with `For` but with the evaluation of your series expansion.

the latter you can solve relatively easy by using `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) in your definitions, e.g.:

```
lhr[t_] = Normal[Series[-k7 x[t] y[t] /. Nsol /. initConst, {t, 0, Ns}]][[1]];
```

That has also the advantage that the series expansion is only done once, not for every new numeric value of `t` again.

You almost certainly will run into problems when you work with this, though: As `For` does not localize its variables it will leave `t` set to the last value in the loop. If you then change your definitions and reevaluate them, they won't work because they expect `t` to be a symbol without a numeric value. To prevent that, you probably want to localize `t` **at definition time**, like so:

```
Module[{t},
lhr[t_] = Normal[Series[-k7 x[t] y[t] /. Nsol /. initConst, {t, 0, Ns}]][[1]];
]
```

This is also a good example why `For` loops in Mathematica always are (at most) the second best choice, as I have explained in this 
[answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2188/169). Here `Do[...,{t,a,b,h}]` (or `Do[...,{t,a,b-h/2,h}]` if you insist on the `<` vs. `<=`) would be shorter and -- at least in my opinion -- much clearer. It would do the same thing but additionally localize `t` and thus not leave `t` behind with a value defined. Note that I have added a section about the differences how the two will handle numeric errors potentially accumulating in the loop variable in the answer mentioned which might be of interest for your use case.