# Implementing four-fermions operators on FeynRules and FeynArts

Tags: warning-messages, feyncalc

I am trying to implement operators of the form
$$
\bar{q}_L \gamma^\mu T^A q_L \bar{q}_L \gamma_\mu  T^A q_L
$$
where T^A are the SU(3) generators and $q_L$ is the Electroweak SU(2) doublet.

I use the same .fr file of the Standard model, i.e. SM.fr, where I added the following operators

```
L81qq:=C81qq/Lambda^2 Module[{ii,jj,kk,kk1,jj1,mu,aa,cc,sp1,sp2,sp3,sp4,cc1,cc2,cc3},  (QLbar[sp1,jj,1,cc].QL[sp2,jj,1,cc2] Ga[mu,sp1,sp2]) T[aa,cc,cc2]T[aa,cc3,cc4](QLbar[sp3,jj1,1,cc3].QL[sp4,jj1,1,cc4] Ga[mu,sp3,sp4])];
```

where the parameters are defined as

```
 Lambda== {
        ParameterType -> External,
        ParameterName -> Lambda,
        BlockName -> DIM6,
      InteractionOrder -> {NP,-1},
        Value -> 1000,
      TeX -> \[CapitalLambda],
        Description -> "Scale of the new physics"}
```

and

```
C81qq== {
        ParameterType -> External,
        ParameterName -> C81qq,
        BlockName -> FourFermion,
        Value -> 1,
      TeX -> Subsuperscript[C,qq,"(8,1)"],
        Description -> "coefficient of O81qq"},
```

Feynrules manages to reproduce the feynman rules of this 4-fermion operator and also the FeynArts output. But, when I try to draw the diagrams via

```
 << HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc`;
```

> Loading FeynCalc from /home/user/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics
>
> FeynCalc 8.2.0 For help, type ?FeynCalc, open FeynCalcRef8.nb or visit www.feyncalc.org
>
> FeynArts 3.9 patched for use with FeynCalc

```
top = CreateTopologies[0, 2 -> 2]; 

diags = 
 InsertFields[top, {F[3, {1}], F[3, {1}]} -> {F[3, {1}], F[3, {1}]}, 
  InsertionLevel -> {Classes}, Model -> "Standard_Model_dijets_FA", 
  GenericModel -> "Standard_Model_dijets_FA", 
  ExcludeParticles -> {V[1], V[2], V[3], S[1], V[4], 
    S[2]}];
```

I get the error

> loading generic model file /home/user/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics/FeynArts/Models/Standard_Model_dijets_FA.gen
>
> TagSetDelayed::tagnf: Tag FourVector not found in -mom_^mu_. >>
>
> Pattern::patvar: First element in pattern Pattern[b_,_] is not a valid pattern name. >>

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you format the code like you did here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59527/precision-problem-with-numerical-solution-of-a-differential-equation?

Comment: Is there a reason `C81qq` and `Lamdba` are followed by `==` instead of a single `=`?

Comment: This is the standard format of Feynrules, I.e. defining new parameters with ==

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to update to FeynCalc 9, FC 8.2 is already outdated. Please use the development version:

https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/Installation#dev_automatic_installation

I'm not using FeynRules myself, but I have already been asked to make FeynCalc compatible with FeynRules+FeynArts and according to the user who needed this, everything worked at the end. So please have a look at this message and the subsequent replies

http://www.feyncalc.org/forum/1034.html

If there are still issues left, you can write to the [mailing list](http://www.feyncalc.org/forum/) or directly to [me](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/Support#e-mail-contact), so we will find a solution.

Cheers,

Vladyslav

Comment: Thanks Vladyslav, I will write to the mailing list because I have still problems.

Answer (score 2):

You need to patch the model for use in FeynCalc:

```
$LoadFeynArts=True;
<<FeynCalc`;
FAPatch[PatchModelsOnly -> True]
```

Comment: Until not so long time ago it wouldn't have worked even with patching, since FeynCalc couldn't work out the relative signs between diagrams with 4-fermion vertices. But since [Issue #46](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/issues/46) was resolved, it indeed works out of the box, as one would expect it. Dev version is required, though.