# Working with Real/Imaginary/Modulus parts of an complex Interpolating Function?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations

From solving *n* times a numerical (complex) equation, like:

```
n = 10;
eq = Range[n];


For[a = 1, a < (n + 1), a++, 
 eq[[a]] = 
  NDSolve[{y''[x] + a*y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1 + I, y'[0] == 1 + 0 I}, 
  y, {x, 0, 30}]]
```

I get the (complex) *n* solutions in the variable *value*:

```
value = Range[n];

For[a = 1, a < (n + 1), a++, 
 value[[a]] = 
   With[{exp = Through[({y} /. First[eq[[a]]])[#]]}, exp &]];
```

Which is a list of 10 complex interpolating functions. I can plot the real and imaginary parts of each element of *value* with no problem.

Now, I'm interested in working with the squared modulus of *value*, *i.e.* its squared real part plus its squared imaginary part. I'm trying to define two new variables as the real and imaginary parts of *value*:

```
valuereal = Range[n];
valueim = Range[n];

For[a = 1, a < (n + 1), a++, 
 valuereal[[a]] = 
   Re[value[[a]]]];

For[a = 1, a < (n + 1), a++, 
 valueim[[a]] = 
   Im[value[[a]]]];
```

But it seems that I can't plot these new variables (maybe I can't define the real/imaginary parts in this way?). How can I work correctly with the real/imaginary part of *value* (an complex interpolating function)?

**Question**: How can work with the real/imaginary parts of an complex Interpolating function?

Note: I tried to work with:

```
Abs[value[[a]]]
```

But I had the same problem.

I'd appreciate all kind of answers a lot.

Comment: there is no need to use `For`. Use `Table` instead. Something like `f[a_] := NDSolve[{y''[x] + a*y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1 + I, y'[0] == 1 + 0 I}, 
   y, {x, 0, 30}];
eq = Table[f[a], {a, 1, n}];`

Comment: Besides what Nasser already suggested, you should also have a look at this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2158/21606 and this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/21606.

Comment: Nasser: 
That was somewhat I already had, but In a (much) simpler (and nicer) form. But my problem still there: how can I name a new variable as the real part of an element of eq?

Comment: Nasser: what does _a_ stand for? I have to suppose that f(a) is the solution function y(x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot distinguish `f[g][x]` and `f[g[x]]`

All your code are in a form like defining `com=Im[sol]`, but when plotting, you plot like `com[x]` which, after inserting com's definition, becomes `Im[sol][x]` instead of `Im[sol[x]]` which will generate the correct result.

So, try use `LeftComposition` instead of your method.

```
com=Im@*sol
Plot[com[x],{x,0,1}]
```

This code will yield desired result.

Hope this post can help you~