# How can I use /. in a For loop

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge table of data which I need to insert all of them in my main function using a For loop. For example, I have

```
subsnum = {{x -> 1., y -> 1.}, {x -> 2., y -> 2.}, {x -> 3., 
y -> 3.}};
FullScalarMasses = {{x^2, y^3}, {x + y, y}};
```

and I want to calculate the Eigenvalues of "FullScalarMasses" for all elements of "subsnum". The code I use is the following

```
For[i = 0, i <= 3, i++, 
es1 = Eigenvalues[FullScalarMasses //. subsnum[[i]]]]
```

however I get this error and can't continue:

```
ReplaceRepeated::reps: {List} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
```

How can I solve the problem? In practice my code is a lot more complicated than this. I have a big data table with more than a million values, and I need to calculate several things for each element of the table. An the only way I can think of is using "ReplaceRepeated" in a For loop. Is there any other way I can do this?

P.S.: I have to calculate many things in the loop at the same time for the same element, so "Table" is not an option.

Comment: The `For` loop starts at `i = 0`. So `subsnum[[i]]` evaluates to `subsnum[[0]]`, which returns the head of the expression, `List`. Then you have the `ReplaceRepeated` error. You can start at `i = 1` to avoid this issue.

Comment: Slightly on a tangent, `For` is highly inefficient on _Mathematica_. I recommend `Do`, which is a native _Mathematica_ function, with the same functionality as, but with significantly faster evaluation than, `For` . That is: `Do[es1 = Eigenvalues[FullScalarMasses //. subsnum[[i]], {i, 3}]`

Comment: @Xavier Thanks a lot for your answer. I was dealing with this for a long time and I never noticed this was the problem. I was sure it's something to do with Replace!

Comment: "I have to calculate many things in the loop at the same time *for the same element*" <- If it is for the same element, then why is Table not an option?  Calculating *many* things is not a problem.  Calculating things which depend on perviously calculated elements (not the same element!) would preclude the use of Table.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the loop at all. This returns all eigenvalues of all three of the matrices defined by subsnum and fullScalarMasses:

```
subsnum = {{x -> 1., y -> 1.}, {x -> 2., y -> 2.}, {x -> 3., y -> 3.}};
fullScalarMasses[x_, y_] := {{x^2, y^3}, {x + y, y}}; 
Eigenvalues[fullScalarMasses[x, y]] /. subsnum

{{-0.414214, 2.41421}, {-2.74456, 8.74456}, {-7.0767, 19.0767}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said the real code is a lot longer and I really need to have a For loop. For this specific example it's possible to do this, as I always do, but for my problem I cannot.

Comment: You can make the function as complicated as you want and the iteration does not change. In other words, by rewriting your problem *as a function* you will be able to iterate it easily.

Answer (score 3):

First rule of learning Mathematica: **Never, ever use `For`!**  It is *never* needed, it is error prone and it encourages bad practices.  If you really want a procedural loop, use [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html), and forget that `For` even exists.  For complex procedural cases, use `While`.

First, consciously or unconsciously you have copied the standard `for` pattern *using 0-based indexing* from C-like languages. Mathematica uses 1-based indexing. This is less likely to happen with `Do`, with which you'll never see any 0-based examples, and which encourages dropping the starting index anyway.

Rewrite your code like this:

```
Do[
  es1 = Eigenvalues[FullScalarMasses //. subsnum[[i]]]],
  {i, 1, Length[subsnum]}
]
```

Then realize that this is simpler:

```
Do[
  es1 = Eigenvalues[FullScalarMasses //. subsnum[[i]]]],
  {i, Length[subsnum]}
]
```

This is even simpler

```
Do[
  es1 = Eigenvalues[FullScalarMasses //. rule]],
  {rule, subsnum}
]
```

The transition to a non-procedural `Table` is immediate:

```
Table[
  Eigenvalues[FullScalarMasses //. rule]],
  {rule, subsnum}
]
```

The jump to a `Map` form or similar is also very straightforward.

Other advantages of `Do` compared to `For`:

- It automatically localizes the iterator while `For` uses global variables (`i` is set permanently)
- All those commas in `For` are too easy to get wrong; `For` has both worse readability and "writeability" than `Do`
- `Do` is faster for very tight loops due to not explicitly setting the iterator

Note 1: I am not advocating against procedural programming here.  I am advocating specifically against `For`, which encourages bad practices in writing Mathematica code and is error prone.

Note 2: There are a few examples where `For` indeed produces the most elegant code. However, these are rare, and I maintain that the disadvantages far outweigh any occasional advantages.  See here and links within: [Are there any cases when For[] loops are reasonable?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2158/12)