# For loop for two variable at the same time

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, procedural-programming, infinite-loop

Can I use for loop for two variables as example show below at the same time?

for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < 10 && y < 10; x++, y++)

Comment: @Nasser I won't mind any method but still at the same time increment in two variables, I was not able to do it.....

Comment: @Nasser It worked Thanks!!

Comment: More idiomatic in *Mathematica* would be something like `Table[expression,{x,0,10},{y,0,10}]`. Depending on what you're doing, you might use something other than `Table`, or even avoid the need for `x` and `y` by using something like `Map`. But you'll have to show us what you're trying to accomplish for us to help with that.

Comment: You should see this Q&A:
 [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/10397).
[Are there any cases when For loops are reasonable?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2158/10397)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`For`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) loop works just fine in the Wolfram Language, so I won't try to dissuade you from using it.  Though I don't use it myself I've seen a resurgence in its use with the new compiler.

```
For[
    x = 0;
    y = 0
    ,
    x < 10 && y < 10
    ,
    x++;
    y++;
    ,
    Print[x, " and ", y]
]
```

results in this print:

```
0 and 0

1 and 1

2 and 2

3 and 3

4 and 4

5 and 5

6 and 6

7 and 7

8 and 8

9 and 9
```