# How to handle exceptions and failures in Mathematica?

Tags: functions, warning-messages, dataset, functional-style, error-trapping

In python I can write fallback values like:

```
def f():
   try: 
     // do smtg
     return stgm
   except:
     // error was met: return fallback
     return fallback
```

and can easily map that function.

In mathematica I have a dataset, I would like to append a column as a result of a function applied to a row, and throw a fallback or handle that error is function fails.

I would like to consider:

- throw a fallback value
- handle the error, by skipping the whole line in the Dataset (like I could do in python Pandas)

In mathematica, if there is an exception, map of the function will be aborted with a Failure. I don't know what to do with this message.

[image]

I looked at :
[Exception/Error handling using returns codes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29283/exception-error-handling-using-returns-codes)

I am looking at simpler pattern that could do:

```
f[row_] := row["col1"] / row["col2"] // handle try except ?

// ds is Dataset 
ds[All, Append[#, "col3" -> f[#]] &]
```

How to do handle try / except exeptions in Mathematica?

Comment: I'd start with [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) and probably look at [`FailureAction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FailureAction.html) too. If you still think you need exceptions *proper* then you should probably look at [`Catch`/`Throw`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FailureAction.html), and you should also take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/634/error-checking-and-trapping-techniques-with-throw-and-catch) too

Comment: related: [29321](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29321/5478)