# How to implement try/catch/end try in Mathematica in the most simple way?

Tags: message-coding, error-trapping

There are lots of question/answers about exception handling in Mathematica. I still find exception handling in Mathematica too complicated to work with.

I find Maple much simpler and easier to understand when it comes to exception handling.

What would be the simplest translation of the following code from Maple to Mathematica?

```
foo:=proc(x,y)
   try
      x/y;
   catch:
      error "I give up, bad input";
   end try;
end proc;
```

The above defines a function `foo`. The main exception handling is done using `try .... catch: ... end try`

The call to `error` terminates the function sends an error message to the caller (if any).

The use of `:` after `catch` means to catch ANY error. (otherwise one can catch specific error.

So when calling the above in Maple this is the result

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And when calling it as `foo(1,1)` no error is generated.

I do not want to set separate functions and define external message string and tags and so on in Mathematica to do the above as shown in [Error checking and trapping techniques with Throw and Catch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/634/error-checking-and-trapping-techniques-with-throw-and-catch) for example which is very good but I find hard to follow and more complicated than in Maple. I'd like everything done inside the `Module`

The `try .. catch... end try` is much simpler to use and understand.

What is the *simplest* way to implement similar code as the above Maple function?

Comment: I was waiting to see how you would respond to Roman's answer as it seems to me the natural approach, *if* I understand the question.  Since you did not I guess I'll ask, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
f[x_, y_] := Check[x/y, $Failed]

f[1, 0]
```

> During evaluation of Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>
> $Failed

In this way you can pass the `$Failed` to the caller and react to it, instead of passing the default of `ComplexInfinity` (which is useful in its own way).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this?

```
f[x_, y_] := Module[{}, Quiet@Check[x/y, Throw["I give up, bad input"]]];

f[1, 0]
(* Throw::nocatch : Uncaught Throw[I give up, bad input] returned to top level. *)
```

Comment: Thanks., but it seems the error do not get cought by caller. i.e. When I tried `g[x_, y_] := Module[{},Check[f[x, y], Throw["f[x,y] threw an error !"]]];` I was expecting to see the error `f[x,y] threw an error !` but instead got the error `I give up, bad input`. Which tells me the throw from `f[x,y]` goes directly to top level bypassing the caller.

Comment: The caller can wrap the called function in `Catch` to stop propagation to the top level and handle it as needed. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way to do that. First define something to validate your output and which will `Throw` a tag if invalid. Then `Catch` that:

```
validateResp // Clear
validateResp[resp_, validator_, error_: Automatic] :=
  If[! TrueQ[validator@resp],
   Throw[resp, Replace[error, Automatic :> $tryCatchTag]],
   resp
   ];
tryCatch // Clear
SetAttributes[tryCatch, HoldFirst];
tryCatch[
  expr_,
  error : _String | Verbatim[Blank][] : "BadValue",
  handler : Except[_String | Verbatim[Blank][]] : (#2 &),
  validator : Except[_String | Verbatim[Blank][]] : (Length[$MessageList] == 0 &)
  ] :=
 Block[{$tryCatchTag = error},
  Catch[
   validateResp[expr, validator, error],
   error,
   handler
   ]
  ]
```

You'd use it like this:

```
tryCatch[
 1/0
 ]

(* Message: Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. *)

(* Out: "BadValue" *)
```

Unfortunately there's no global sense of "if an error occurred" so by default my `validator` just checks if any messages were generated when evaluating, but this can be anything. You can also put a deeper `validateResp` in there if you want. You can also easily throw your own errors and catch anything like:

```
tryCatch[
 If[! TrueQ[n > 2],
   validateResp[False, False &, "BadN"],
  1/0
  ],
 _
 ]

"BadN"
```

Which if the first test passed would give you

```
tryCatch[
 If[False,
   validateResp[False, False &, "BadN"],
  1/0
  ],
 _
 ]

(* Message: Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. *)

(* Out: _ *)
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is still way more complicated than Maple's :). But it does work.

Comment: @Nasser yeah it’s a different language so it’ll have different error handling semantics. Inescapable product of the flexibility of the language

Comment: yes, ofcourse. Sometimes I think Mathematica is way "too flexible" with the side effects it can become "too complicated" as well.