# How to catch this error from TeXForm? TeXForm::unspt

Tags: warning-messages, latex, error-trapping

I get lots of error from using TeXForm in 12.3.1 on some solutions that contain `DifferentialRoot` written in the new `HolonomicBoxes` that WRI is now using.

But my attempts to use `Quiet[Check[]]` in order to at least capture this error and replace the Latex with some message saying it failed to convert are not working.

What is the correct way to do this? Here is a MWE

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = (2*x + 1)*y''[x] - 2*(2*x^2 - 1)*y'[x] - 4*(x + 1)*y[x] == 0;
sol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
TeXForm[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The message is `TeXForm::unspt`. So I tried

```
result = Quiet[Check[TeXForm[sol], "FAILED", TeXForm::unspt]]
```

But this did not work. I still the same output in `result` with the beep. I was expecting `result` to say "FAILED".

I then tried

```
result = Quiet[Check[TeXForm[sol], "FAILED"]]
```

And this also did not work. I then tried

```
TeXForm[InputForm@sol]
```

Now the error message went away, but the Latex generated do not compile, as it contains lots of `$\unicode{f818}` stuff, which Latex compiler does not like.

```
\text{$\{\{$y[x] -$>$ DifferentialRoot[Function[$\{\unicode{f818}$, $\unicode{f817}\}$, $\{$(-4 -
   4*$\unicode{f817}$)*$\unicode{f818}$[$\unicode{f817}$] + (2 -
   4*$\unicode{f817}{}^{\wedge}$2)*Derivative[1][$\unicode{f818}$][$\unicode{f817}$] + (1 +
   2*$\unicode{f817}$)*Derivative[2][$\unicode{f818}$][$\unicode{f817}$] == 0, $\unicode{f818}$[0] ==
   C[1], Derivative[1][$\unicode{f818}$][0] == C[2]$\}$]][x]$\}\}$
```

And I really do not want my Latex all as `\text` anyway.

I simply would like to trap this error when the program is running and replace the Latex with simple say `\text{unable to compile}` instead.

But I do not know how to catch it. Trapping and handling error in Mathematica is the hardest thing for me as it is too complicated to figure the right way to do it.

Any suggestions?

12.3.1

Reference  [catch-mathematica-warnings-errors-without-displaying-them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310076/catch-mathematica-warnings-errors-without-displaying-them)

Reference [how-to-implement-try-catch-end-try-in-mathematica-in-the-most-simple-way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215483/how-to-implement-try-catch-end-try-in-mathematica-in-the-most-simple-way)

Comment: The message is generated when the FE typesets the output. So `Check` and `Quiet` won't work, because it is done after the execution of your code. You could set ``BoxForm`$NewHolonomicBoxes = False`` but that doesn't seem to be what you ask for.  Or you could use ``Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[sol]``, but again you get no error.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2  I actually tried this also before, but it does not do what I want, since the output gives similar result as when doing `TeXForm[InputForm@sol]` which contains all those `\unicode{f818}` stuff which does not compile with lualatex. So I thought better to get the error and catch it so I can avoid all this Latex.  Now what I do is check if the ode solution has `DifferentialRoot` in it, and just do not call `TeXForm` at all. This is the best solution for now. And it is working.  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0uZk.png)

Comment: This gives the error (but twice for some reason -- once in the kernel, once in the FE?): ``MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm] &@TeXForm[sol]``. So `Check` works on it: `Check[MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm] &@TeXForm[sol], Null]`