# Debugging Mathematica Code

Tags: debugging

In various integrated development environments, such as Microsoft Visual Studio, there is an integrated debugger where you can step through code sections, examine the state of variables and figure out where things are going wrong. With more complex Mathematica programs a debugger would be an extremely valuable asset. I was wondering what people use to debug Mathematica programs?

Is Wolfram Workbench the only/best solution?

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2230/8

Comment: How to use the built-in debugger: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8363520/879601

Comment: I use `Sow` and `Reap` frequently to dig data out from the insides of deeply nested expressions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you got 4 choices:

1. Workbench. Probably the most useful of the debuggers.
2. Mathematica has a small debugger: Evaluation -> Debugger
3. There is [DebugTrace](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/debugtrace/debugtrace.html) from David (perhaps there are other packages)
4. Use Print, Trace(Scan)[], etc type of functions.

Comment: [SO Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362170) on lower side of page there is mention of using *Mathematica*'s built-in debugger.

Answer (score 32):

I found a curious style of debugging that I call "Epicsauce Debugging Level 2."

First you type this:

```
x = 0;
While[True,
  Pause[1];
  (*Dynamic[x]*) x++
];
```

Then you highlight the `Dynamic[x]` and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Then you execute the cell and BE AMAZED!!! It's quite hilarious, but I wonder how useful it would be for more serious code.

I've already been using this for some minor things, like to check that a value is actually being modified. The fact that you can place it right by the variable itself is conceptually significant, I think.

**Edit:** This is actually pretty cool. Here's one practical use. You know when you compose a bunch of stuff, like a graphics expression:

[image]

And then your script starts getting a little complicated, and you aren't even sure if the issue is with one of your small components or it's an issue with the final composition? Well you can do this:

[image]

Remember that's a live, rotatable object in the comment. One that auto-updates. The nice thing here is that you can debug *individual* components without breaking out of the flow of your program as a whole.

**Edit2:** You can highlight the line where the cuboid is being defined and hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter to only evaluate that line and not the whole expression, and see your changes in the comment. It appears that expressions that return `Null` (such as those ending with `;`) aren't replaced when you Ctrl+Shift+Enter on them. Also remember that Ctrl+. will let you quickly select whole expressions.

Comment: There is no need to "Excuse the necromancy" -- in fact there is a [badge](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/badges/17/necromancer) for posting late-but-good answers!

Comment: Mind. Blown. How exactly was this discovered??

Comment: I'd vote this up for "best hack of 2013" if there were such an award :)

Comment: Hi, @amr. Is it still working now? What do you mean by "highlight the Dynamic[x] and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter"? I can not see any amazing thing happen except that Mathematica just hangs there without any output

Comment: @matheorem I also had that issue. Here are some extra details: Copy paste the While code into your notebook. Highlight Dynamic[x] inside of the comment and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. On my laptop the Dynamic[x] changes to a number. Then right click on the cell bracket and choose "Evaluate Cells" in the menu. Then be amazed then abort with Alt+. for example.