# What are ways to debug while Mathematica is running?

Tags: debugging

I would like to know if we can "watch some values" during running time of *Mathematica*. I remember that `C` and `Pascal` compiler allow us to "add watch" on some variables. Some times I use a check point "if keypressed print...". But the latter style is unavailable here.

Comment: Related:[this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/debugging-mathematica-code),[this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/mathematica-debuggability) and many other questions here and on Stackoverflow [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8362170/615464).

Comment: You can always [evaluate in subsession](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/EvaluateInSubsession.html)