# How to use Message with an error string without predefining it first?

Tags: message-coding

I need a very simple error reporting using [Message](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html). But I do not want to pre-define each error message separately as shown [What are the best practices / most common / idiomatic ways to report errors in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29321/what-are-the-best-practices-most-common-idiomatic-ways-to-report-errors-in-m) for example, and in many other places.

I'd like to just do `Message["my error message"]` or something like this, without having to do  `foo::message1="...."` and `foo::message2="...."`  and then later write `Message[foo::message1]` or  `Message[foo::message2]`. This will be specific to one module, so I do not need to share these messages with other modules.

Here is an example that works, but require one to define name for the message first:

```
foo[x_] := Module[{},
   foo::error = "x<0 detected";
   If[x < 0, Message[foo::error], x]
   ];
r = foo[-1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'd like to be something like

```
foo[x_] := Module[{},
   If[x < 0, Message["x<0 detected"], x]
   ];
```

But the above does not work.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there a syntax that allows one to build the Message on the fly without predefining it first?

I tried `foo::"argx"` which is supposed to allow one on the fly to build a message, but ofcourse the message now does not mean what I want:

```
foo[x_] := Module[{},
   If[x < 0, Message[foo::"argx", "foo", "x<0 detected"], x]
   ];
r = foo[-1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If it is not possible to do with `Message`, is there something similar to `Message` that allows me to issue error message but leave the function unevaluated? I do not want to use Throw/Catch, etc.. I want to keep things simple for now.

**Update:**

Karsten 7 method in answer below seems to work well. I only need to define one named message, so no problem. This is what I can do now:

```
foo[x_] := Module[{},
   General::error = "`1`";
   If[x < 0, Message[foo::error, "x<0 detected"]; Return[]];
   If[x > 10, Message[foo::error, "x>10 detected"]; Return[]];

   (*all checked, now apply the algorithm*)
   x
   ];
```

Comment: You could try writing to the `$Messages` channel using `OpenWrite` and `Write`.

Comment: You could use [`Assert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assert.html) instead of the `If` statements and define an [`$AssertFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$AssertFunction.html) that `Throw`s an error message.

Comment: @Karsten7. Yes, I could do that. But it is more complicated, and according to accepted answer in [what-are-the-best-practices-most-common-idiomatic-ways-to-report-errors-in-m](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29321/what-are-the-best-practices-most-common-idiomatic-ways-to-report-errors-in-m)  this is not recommended way, which I agree. Someone have to catch the error. I was looking for simple basic method, and I think Message[] does the job well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify a general error message that only consists of a placeholder

```
General::error = "`1`";
```

and then use

```
foo[x_] := Module[{}, If[x < 0, Message[foo::error, "x<0 detected"], x]];
r = foo[-1]
```

> ```
> foo::error: x<0 detected
> ```