# Inspecting the evaluation stack on computation abort

Tags: debugging, resource-management

It happens often that a computation starts consuming more memory or time when it encounters an expression with elements in the input that are in some unexpected form.

Is there some way to abort computation, while capturing the evaluation stack of `Mathematica`? seeing what functions and what arguments are taking more resources than usual would be extremely helpful to debug

Comment: You can start here: [29323](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29323/5478)

Comment: With addition of [Aborting evaluation when the memory exceeds a certain limit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2789/5478)