# What is an example of of idiomatic "typed" WolframScript?

Tags: scripting, data-types

I'd like to make my own "typed function" in WolframScript. Suppose the type we desire is called `money`, and we'd like to make a function called `doubleOurMoney` which doubles any `money` argument but throws an error on everything else. How do we do this?

**Attempt:** This isn't quite right but perhaps is a good starting point:

```
doubleOurMoney[money[x_Real]] := money[2 x]
doubleOurMoney[money[2.0]]         (* Should return money[4.], and does. *)

doubleOurMoney[money["nonsense"]]  (* How do we make this throw an error? *)
doubleOurMoney[2]                  (* How do we make this throw an error? *)
doubleOurMoney["nonsense"]         (* How do we make this throw an error? *)
doubleOurMoney[symbol]             (* How do we make this throw an error? *)
```

**Questions:**

1. How do we throw "type errors" in this context?
2. Right now `money` accepts real numbers as arguments; how could we make it take any "number" as an argument (Integer, etc) but throw an error on everything else?
3. Is my attempt at "typed WolframScript" an idiomatic approach to type-checking in Wolfram? If not, what is the idiomatic approach here to check that inputs to a function are sensible?

Comment: There is probably a duplicate for this question, but I don't see it offhand.

Comment: related: [What are the best practices / most common / idiomatic ways to report errors in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29321/142)

Answer (score 11):

Here is an idiom used by many built-in functions to achieve this effect:

```
doubleOurMoney::badarg = "`1` should be of the form money[number]";
doubleOurMoney[money[x_?NumericQ]] := money[2 x];
doubleOurMoney[args___] := (
    Message[doubleOurMoney::badarg, args];
    Null /; False
)
```

Here I'm using [`_?NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) instead of [`_Real`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Real.html) to make your function work on all numeric input.  That first definition will only fire for numeric inputs of the right form, but the second definition will work for any input.  The second definition will issue a message telling the user what type of input is needed:

```
doubleOurMoney[money[2]]
(* money[4] *)

doubleOurMoney[3]

During evaluation of doubleOurMoney::badarg: 3 should be of the form money[number]
(* doubleOurMoney[3] *)

doubleOurMoney["bob"]

During evaluation of doubleOurMoney::badarg: bob should be of the form money[number]
(* doubleOurMoney["bob"] *)
```

That last bit of trickery is so that your function, after issuing a message, returns unevaluated.  You could replace the `Null /; False` with `$Failed` just as easily.

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to declare separately (at the beginning) that `money` only takes form `money[x_?NumericQ]` and for all other `money[args___]` we throw an error? And then that way we don't have to do it within `doubleOurMoney` but can just say `doubleOurMoney` takes a `money[..]` (however it is defined).

Comment: That is a bit different - you could make a definition for money, like `money[ arg: Except[_?NumericQ] ] := (Message[ money::badarg];$Failed)`.  In that case, `money` would return `$Failed` for any non-numeric input.

Comment: @JasonB.  or even better use `SetValid` on valid data (and only run the check on stuff without the bit) and then `doubleOurMoney` need only check for the valid bit.